# Ошибка кодировки в Python: readline() при чтении utf-8 файла ругается: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, кодировка, python-2.x, unicode

Пытаюсь читать файл портов от IANA. Он сохранен в кодировке UTF-8 w/o BOM.
Но на одной из строк функция `readline()` ругается вот таким вот образом

> 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98
>   in position 7938: character maps to
>   <"undefined">

Строка в файле выглядит следующим образом:

> #                          Jim Harlan <"jimh&infowest.com">

Какой костыль придумать для этого? Или есть прямой путь решения?

**UPD**

Ибо костыль в виде удаления данной строки пойдет (причем она, почему-то вот такая одна), но только на время отладки, ибо потом вдруг что, партнеры будут рвать волосы на моей голове. Так же выложу код, которым пользуюсь для данной операции:

```
try:
    file = open(path, 'r')
    while True:
        line = file.readline()
        if(not line):
            break
        print(line)
finally:
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

попробуйте использовать встроенную библиотеку codecs:

```
import codecs
fileObj = codecs.open( "someFilePath", "r", "utf_8_sig" )
text = fileObj.read() # или читайте по строке
fileObj.close()
```

Comment: Так ошибка нашлась еще раньше:

>'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 29-30: character maps to ><undefined>

Comment: Добавил в вопрос некоторые поправки.

Comment: для utf-8 с BOM нужно поменять encoding в open() на "utf_8_sig"

Comment: Пишет, что он без BOM. Хм, а последняя версия вообще другого формата и в ANSI, дурдом

Comment: проблема решилась или вы случайно пометили мой ответ?

Comment: Можно сказать, что 50/50. Проблема с первым файлом решилась удалением злополучной строки. Новый файл в другом формате. Поэтому, пожалуй вы правы, это была случайный всплеск радости. Но плюсик ваш:)

Comment: Не используйте codecs, который может некорректно работать с режимом универсальных строк. Вместо этого [`io.open()` можно использовать.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/591955/23044)

Answer (score 9):

Чтобы прочитать текстовый файл, закодированный с использованием utf-8 кодировки в Питоне, можно использовать `io.open()` функцию, которая доступна как [встроенная `open()` в Питоне 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import io

with io.open(path, encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        process(line)
```

Если в файле возможны ошибки, связанные с кодировкой: сама кодировка верна, но могут быть мелкие погрешности, тогда можно передать `errors='ignore'` обработчик ошибок [(или другое значение в зависимости от конкретной ситуации)](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#error-handlers).

Не используйте `codecs`, который может некорректно работать с режимом универсальных строк.
Не нужно менять вашу кодовую страницу на `cp65001`, чтобы utf-8 файл прочитать.
Если хотите напечатать Unicode в Виндовую консоль, то см. [Как из Python вывести на Windows-консоль строку в Юникоде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/141035/23044)

Answer (score 2):

Постоянно ловил эту ошибку, раз за разом. Решение увидел [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284269/why-doesnt-python-recognize-my-utf-8-encoded-source-file/14284404#14284404).

```
import codecs
file = codecs.open( "yourFile", "r", "utf-8" )
data = file.read()
file .close()
```

- `chcp 65001` в командной строке

Этими не сложными действиями проблема решена.

Comment: я не вижу связи между чтением файла и `chcp 65001`. Не говоря о том, что `chcp 65001` это решение с дефектами, которое следует избегать в пользу [решений, которые Unicode API используют типа win-unicode-console или PEP 528](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5419/4279)

Answer (score 1):

```
file = codecs.open(path, encoding='utf-8', mode='r')
```

Comment: Так пробовали уже, не заработало

Comment: 'utf-8', а не 'utf-8-sig'

Comment: Пробовал. До этого был ответ с utf-8.