# Как из Python вывести на Windows-консоль строку в Юникоде?

Tags: python, windows, кодировка, консоль, unicode

Простой print() не срабатывает. Интерпретатор валится с жалобой на то, что он сам не может сконвертировать Юникод в ту кодировку, которая используется в Windows-консоли. Может быть ему можно как-то помочь? Возможно, есть какой-нибудь модуль, который умеет это делать.

Comment: `encode`+`decode`+`cp1251`

Comment: [Как я боролся с кодировками в консоли](http://habrahabr.ru/post/117236/)

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Проблемы с кодировкой Python 2.7](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229015/23044)

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Python, Unicode, and the Windows console](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5419/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console

Answer (score 16):

***Обновление:*** [Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-528-change-windows-console-encoding-to-utf-8) использует Unicode API для ввода/вывода в консоль как упомянутый ниже [`win_unicode_console`](https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console) пакет (подробнее в [PEP 528](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0528/)). По умолчанию  поддерживаются произвольные Unicode символы. *Простой `print(unicode_string)` теперь работает без установки дополнительного ПО* (консольный шрифт, поддерживающий желаемые символы, по прежнему нужно настраивать).

На границе с Windows-консолью используется Unicode, внутри `sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout`, `sys.stderr` используют utf-8 кодировку. Это может сломать код, который использовал двоичный интерфейс для вывода в консоль и соответственно использовал OEM codepage, к примеру cp866 кодировку. cp866 не совместима с utf-8, [можно получить кракозябры в таком случае](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229015/23044). Необходимо либо исправить код, чтобы он текст, а не байты в консоль выводил, либо выставить `%PYTHONLEGACYWINDOWSIOENCODING%` переменную окружения, чтобы старое поведение восстановить.

Поведение для перенаправленного ввода в файл, в канал (pipe) осталось прежним: используется `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` по умолчанию (ANSI codepage, к примеру cp1251).

---

Это [давняя проблема в Питоне](http://bugs.python.org/issue1602). Пакет [`win_unicode_console`](https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console) добавляет наиболее полную поддержку Юникода как для вывода, так и для ввода текста в консоли—можно использовать этот пакет *не меняя своего исходного кода* c помощью включённого `run` модуля:

```
C:\> py -m pip install win-unicode-console
C:\> py -m run path\your_script.py
```

Это позволяет печатать произвольные Юникод символы, даже те которые не представимы в текущей кодировке консоли (такой как `cp866`), например, `print(u'\N{snowman}')` -> ☃ (могут быть корректно показаны все BMP Unicode символы, поддерживаемые настроенными шрифтами. Даже не-BMP символы можно скопировать в другие программы из консоли).

---

В качестве одноразового решения (без новых пакетов), можно установить переменную окружения `PYTHONIOENCODING`:

```
C:\> set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
C:\> py path\your_script.py > output_in_utf8.txt
```

Оба решения, не добавляют жёстко прописанную кодировку внутрь скрипта, делая их более переносимыми.

Answer (score 3):

Вот простой пример вывода в консоль текста (Python 2.7)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('cp866')  # Устанавливаем кодировку вывода консоли.

print(u'Произвольный текст')
```

Comment: Зачем `reload(sys)`?

Comment: @neoascetic: изменение кодировки по умолчанию не рекомендуется (это может сломать библиотеки, которые этого не ожидают), `sys.setdefaultencoding()` функция удалена по умолчанию, `reload(sys)` делает её снова доступной.

Answer (score 1):

вполне возможен такой вариант:

## код

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
def out_console(txt=''):
    print txt.decode('utf8') # работает
    print txt.encode('utf8') # вызовет ошибку

a='проверка текста'
out_console(a)
```

Хочу обратить ваше внимание, что оператор "`print`" лучше сделать через `sys.stdout` -- объект файла. Это позволит избежать проблем совместимости между `python2` и `python3`.

Чтобы не было одноразовым вариантом, как в ответе выше, можно сделать в самом скрипте следующее:

## код

```
# -*- codng: utf8 -*-
import sys
sys.putenv('PYTHONIOENCODING', 'utf8')
```

Этого будет достаточно, чтобы установить кодировку для текущего процесса и всех дочерних. В моём примере лишнее, так как первая строка в моём скрипте как раз затачивает интерпретатор под кодировку `utf8`.

Разумеется, сам код должен быть сохранён в кодировке `utf8`. Для этих целей рекомендую редактор `Geany` (универсальное решение), либо `Kate` (преимущественно `Linux`).

Comment: суть использования `PYTHONIOENCODING` в том, что это переменная *окружения* -- она может быть разной в зависимости от обстоятельств, что позволяет использовать один и тот же скрипт на разных системах, не залезая в его исходный код -- это не нормально, если приходится программы переписывать только потому что система (ОС) язык поменяла. В нормальных обстоятельствах устанавливать `PYTHONIOENCODING` не нужно: из локали берётся кодировка (LANG, LC_CTYPE, LC_ALL, LANGUAGE переменные на Юникс), или виндовая/консольная codepage используются.