# Подсчет и вывод самых повторяющихся строк

Tags: python, файлы, сортировка, строки

Всем доброго дня!

Проблема следующая: имеется текстовый файл (`example.txt`), в котором около полумиллиона строк(как уникальных, так и нет). Нужно из него записать в новый файл (`out.txt`) топ повторяющихся строк + кол-во повторений этой строки в изначальном файле.

Помогите пожалуйста с реализацией. Буду очень признателен.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы найти 10 самых частых строк в файле и напечатать их в лексикографическом порядке:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(line.strip() for line in sys.stdin)
for line, n in sorted(c.most_common(10)):
    print(n, line)
```

Пример, если сохранить этот код в `топ-cтрок` файл и дать разрешение на исполнение `chmod +x топ-cтрок`:

```
$ ./топ-cтрок <example.txt >out.txt
```

Или [на Windows (если `.py` не присутствует в `%PATHEXT%`)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9037346/4279):

```
C:\> py топ-cтрок <example.txt >out.txt
```

Чтобы [отсортировать входной файл, который не помещается в памяти, можно использовать временные файлы](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16954837/4279). Чтобы найти дубликаты в уже отсортированном файле, можно использовать [`itertools.groupby()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13655169/4279).

Байты в файле декодируются в Юникодный текст, используя `sys.stdin.encoding` или если чтение происходит из файла, открытого внутри скрипта (`open(filename)`), то используется `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` кодировка (что-нибудь вроде `cp1251` на Винде и `utf-8` на Маке, Linux). Если необходимо использовать другую кодировку, то следует задать `encoding` параметр у `open()` вызова или установить `PYTHONIOENCODING` переменную окружения, чтобы изменить кодировку ввода/вывода (stdin/stdout/stderr).

По умолчанию сортировка происходит в лексикографическом порядке для Юникодных символов (`ord(c)`), например, порядок сортировки больших (`А`) и маленьких букв (`а`) может отличаться от результатов `sort` утилиты, которая использует текущую локаль по умолчанию (сравни результаты: `sort` и `LC_ALL=C sort`). Чтобы принять во внимание особенности сортировки в заданном языке, можно использовать [`russian_strings.sort(key=icu.Collator.createInstance(icu.Locale('ru')).getSortKey)`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446833/23044). Возможно также полезно провести нормализацию строк (`unicodedata.normalize()`), чтобы одинаково `ё` (`u'\u0451'`) и `ё` (`u'\u0435\u0308'`) сортировать.

---

Если возникают проблемы с печатью Юникодных строк на Винде, то установи `win-unicode-console` пакет, см.: [Как из Python вывести на Windows-консоль строку в Юникоде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/359348/23044) На других системах достаточно [локаль настроить](https://askubuntu.com/q/33025/3712) и/или [установить переменные окружения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/386671/23044) `LANG`, `LC_ALL`, `LC_CTYPE`, `PYTHOIOENCODING` (последнее -- если вывод перенаправлен), например:

```
$ LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 ./топ-cтрок <example.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Заведите словарь, в котором ключом будет строка, значением количество повторений строки. Прочитали строку, нет такой в словаре - создаём ключ со значением 1. Есть - увеличиваем значение. Потом сортируем и выводим пары ключ:значение.

Comment: а можно пример кода, пожалуйста?

Comment: Примеры кода:

[Запись и чтение файлов](http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D3%F7%E5%E1%ED%E8%EA_Python_2.6#.D0.97.D0.B0.D0.BF.D0.B8.D1.81.D1.8C_.D0.B8_.D1.87.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.84.D0.B0.D0.B9.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B2)

[Словари и их сортировка](http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D3%F7%E5%E1%ED%E8%EA_Python_2.6#.D0.A1.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.B8)

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Под *nix можно так:

```
cat example.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr > out.txt
```

Если нужно только 10 топовых, к примеру:

```
cat example.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 10 > out.txt
```

Comment: И действительно - так гораздо проще. Спасибо.

Comment: Сообщит скорость выполнения такой команды, использование ОЗУ во время работы для вашего миллиона строк.