# Поиск упорядоченной подстроки в строке Python

Tags: python, строки

Что-то встрял, хотя задание ерунда.

Задание: упорядоченная подстрока.

УСЛОВИЕ:
Построить функционал который будет находить в строке подстроку максимальной длины, в которой буквы упорядочены в алфавитном порядке.
ВХОД: строка
ВЫХОД: подстрока

Пример:

```
s = "sabrrtuwacaddabra"
"abrrtuw"
```

Comment: Если следующий символ строки больше или равен предыдущему - увеличиваем последовательность. Нет - сбрасываем. Пройдете по всей строке - найдете самую длинную такую последовательность.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов В том то и загвоздка что не знал, что следующие элемент в алфавите может быть больше. Спасибо.

Comment: В общем случае он может не быть больше, тогда держите строку "abcd...z" с алфавитом и сравнивайте индексы вхождения :-)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: "больше или равен" является непростым вопросом в не-ascii случае. В общем случае, что-нибудь вроде [`PyICU.Collator` необходимо испрользовать](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26505661/4279).

Comment: @jfs ну это уже совсем сурово

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В любой кодировке в алфавитном порядке увеличивается и номер буквы, т.е.

'a'<'b'; 'а'<'б';

и т.п.

```
s = "sabrrtuwacaddabra" 
final_out=""
output = ""
prev=""
for cur in s:
    if cur>=prev:
        output +=cur
        if len(final_out)<len(output):
            final_out=output
    else:
        output = cur
    prev=cur
print final_out
```

Comment: В общем-то нет: в win1251 и в cp866, если я ничего не путаю, буква "ё" стоит в кодовой таблице особняком.

Comment: Спасибо за поправку, не знал если честно.

Comment: Да и в [юникоде](http://unicode-table.com/ru/#cyrillic) код Ё < А < я < ё

Answer (score 2):

Наивное решение, которое использует сравнение символов по умолчанию (основанное на порядковом номере `ord(char)`), может вернуть неверный результат для не-ascii символов, поэтому сравнение необходимо проводить, используя функцию специфичную для заданного алфавита:

```
def longest_alphabetical_substring(text, rank=lambda char: char):
    if not text: # empty
        return text
    longest = substr = []
    prev = text[0]
    for char in text[1:]:
        substr.append(prev)
        if rank(prev) > rank(char): # end of alphabetical substring
            if len(longest) < len(substr):
                longest = substr
            substr = []
        prev = char
    substr.append(prev)
    return type(prev)().join(substr if len(longest) < len(substr) else longest)
```

Здесь `rank` функция задаёт порядок букв. Сравнение по умолчанию перестаёт работать даже для текста с одним языком:

```
print(longest_alphabetical_substring("sabrrtuwacaddabra")) # OK ascii
# -> abrrtuw
print(longest_alphabetical_substring(u"абвгдеёжка")) #XXX WRONG!
# -> абвгдеё
```

Чтобы исправить, можно использовать Юникодное сравнение:

```
import icu # PyICU

rank = icu.Collator.createInstance(icu.Locale('ru')).getSortKey
print(longest_alphabetical_substring(u"абвгдеёжка", rank))
# -> абвгдеёжк
```

Чтобы поддерживать буквы, которые могут состоять из нескольких символов, можно использовать `\X` регулярное выражение, которое ищет grapheme cluster в тексте:

```
import regex as re # $ pip install regex

print(longest_alphabetical_substring(u"абвгдеёжка")) #XXX WRONG!
# -> абвгдее
print(longest_alphabetical_substring(re.findall(r"\X", u"абвгдеёжка"))) #XXX WRONG!
# -> абвгдеё
print(longest_alphabetical_substring(re.findall(r"\X", u"абвгдеёжка"), rank))
# -> абвгдеёжк
print(longest_alphabetical_substring(re.findall(r"\X", u"абвгдеёжка")))
# -> абвгдеёжк
print(longest_alphabetical_substring(re.findall(r"\X", u"абвгдеёжка"), rank))
# -> абвгдеёжк
```

В первой и последних двух строчках используется ненормализированная буква `ё`:

```
>>> print(ascii(u"ё"))
'\u0435\u0308'
```

Предпоследний пример случайно дал верный результат и без `rank` функции, но на это не стоит рассчитывать и следует всегда передавать соответствующую алфавиту `rank` функцию.

Для произвольного алфавита, заданного как упорядоченный список строк, можно определить `rank` как это показано в [ответе @Artem`а](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446463/23044):

```
rank = dict(zip(alphabet, range(len(alphabet)))).__getitem__
```

Answer (score 1):

А я бы сделал по-другому:

```
def find_longest(s, key=lambda x: x):
    max_start = 0
    max_len = 0
    cur_start = 0
    cur_len = 1

    for i in range(1, len(s)):
        if key(s[i-1]) <= key(s[i]):
            cur_len += 1
        else:
            if cur_len > max_len:
                max_len = cur_len
                max_start = cur_start
            cur_start = i
            cur_len = 1

    if cur_len > max_len:
        max_len = cur_len
        max_start = cur_start

    return s[max_start:max_start+max_len]
```

Получилось немного длиннее, чем у @Artem, но по идее более оптимально, т.к. в цикле не используется конкатенация строк.
Пример использования:

```
>>> find_longest("sabrrtuwacaddabra")
'abrrtuw'
```

Используем кастомную ключевую функцию:

```
>>> letters_map = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, r=5, s=6, t=7, u=8, w=9)
>>> find_longest("sabrrtuwacaddabra", key=lambda x: letters_map[x])
'abrrtuw'
```

Comment: Хорошее решение, но в случае входной строки вида 'nab' на выходе имеем n, а должны 'ab'

Comment: @OstapBender, исправил

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так:

```
def find_longest(string, letters_map):
    longest = ""
    current = string[0]
    for l in string[1:]:
        if letters_map[current[-1]] <= letters_map[l]:
            current += l
        else:
            if len(longest) < len(current):
                longest = current
            current = l
    return longest

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from string import ascii_lowercase
    letters_map = dict(zip(ascii_lowercase, range(len(ascii_lowercase))))
    print(find_longest("sabrrtuwacaddabra", letters_map))
```

letters_map - словарь с символами и рангом символа. Обязательно чтобы все символы в строке имели ранг в этом словаре

Comment: Решение хорошее, но загвоздка в том, что это начальное задание с pybursa. Так что решение должно быть намного проще я думаю, на уровне новичка.

Answer (score 0):

```
def longest(n, *args):
    lst = [[n]]
    for s in args:
        if s > n: lst[-1].append(s)
        else:
            n = s
            lst.append([s])
    return ''.join(max(lst))

s = longest(*'abcdabcababcdeab')
print(s)
abcde
```