# Python. Сортировка по алфавиту списка словарей

Tags: python, json

Имеется список словарей следующего содержания.

```
guys_json = [
       {
         "id": 3, 
         "full_name": "Ффффф", 
         "post": "Водитель", 
         "image": "xxx.jpg"},     
       {
         "id": 20, 
         "full_name": "Рррр", 
         "post": "Повар", 
         "image": "yyy.jpg"}, 
       {
         "id": 11, 
         "full_name": "Аааа", 
         "post": "Директор", 
         "image": "tre.jpg"},
       ....]
```

Необходимо отсортировать его  в алфавитном порядке средствами python по полю 'full name' и раскидать объекты в категории по буквам кириллического алфавита ("А", "Б"... "Я"). Подскажите, пожалуйста, с какой стороны подойти к решению

Comment: [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) чтобы получить список, а потом его [отсортировать](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) и далее [группировать](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

Comment: Раскидать по первой букве легко (особенно если отсортирован список по алфавиту), но это другой вопрос. Задайте его отдельно. Более того не обязательно сортировать, если раскидки это всё что вам нужно в итоге. Что вы хотите получить, если первая буква не из кириллицы?

Comment: похожий вопрос: [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by values of the dictionary in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/72899/4279)

Comment: да, ввожу в заблуждение вопросом, уже разобрался

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Данные в вопросе не являются JSON объектом, например, `json.loads()` выкинет ошибку.

Если интерпертировать данные как исходный код Питона, тогда `guys_json` (вводящее в заблуждение имя) является обычным списком словарей (никакого отношения к JSON-формату, кроме того что синтаксис похож (как и задумано)).

Легко отсортировать список словарей по значению заданного поля:

```
list_of_dicts.sort(key=lambda d: d['full_name'])
```

Уже есть готовая функция, которую можно вместо `lambda` использовать:

```
from operator import itemgetter

list_of_dicts.sort(key=itemgetter('full_name'))
```

Обе вызова сортируют, используя лексикографический порядок, что для не-ASCII символов может быть не то что нужно. См. [Поиск упорядоченной подстроки в строке Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446833/23044).

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ

Answer (score 0):

Решение следующее

Создаем пустой словарь отсортированных элементов

```
leadership_list_json_sorted = {}
```

Идем по первым буквам полей 'full_name'и пользуемся методом словаря setdefault, если такого ключа (буквы алфавита) нет, делаем ее ключом и добавляем объект в качестве значения, если ключ присутствует, просто добавляем объект

```
    for item in json.loads(guys_json):
        guys_json_sorted.setdefault(item['full_name'][0].lower(), []).append(item)
```

Для каждой буквы делаем свою сортировку

```
    for char in guys_json_sorted:
        guys_json_sorted[char].sort(key=lambda x: x['full_name'], reverse=False)

    guys_json_sorted = json.dumps(leadership_list_json_sorted, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: **1-** не используйте вводящие в заблуждение имена. JSON это текстовый формат, используемый для сохранения объектов ввиде текста. `{}` в исходном коде Питона -- это словарь (`type({}) == dict`), это не текст (`str` тип). Вы с тем же успехом можете слова pickle, yaml, xml, csv, etc в имена добавлять -- это также неправильно как использовать `json` в этих именах. **2-** Посмотрите как ваш код можно улучшить используя `collections.defaultdict` **3-** Ваш код игнорирует [проблемы сортировки не-ASCII текста](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446833/23044) -- хотя для вашего примера это и не важно.