# Сортировка записей в базе по не стандартному алфавиту

Tags: python, django

В общем есть онлайн-словарь кабардино-черкесского языка на Django. У этого языка кириллический алфавит, но фишка этого алфавита состоит в том, что в нем есть такое понятие как буквосочетания, к примеру: "кхъ", "тl", "пl", "гъ", "хъу" и т.д. Другая фишка в том, что алфавитный порядок отличается от стандартной кириллицы. [Статья в Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C#.D0.A1.D0.BE.D0.B2.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B9_.D0.BA.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BB.D0.BB.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B9_.D0.B0.D0.BB.D1.84.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.B8.D1.82). И в связи с этим возникло две задачи:

Задача №1:
Нужно сделать так, чтобы машина воспринимала эти буквосочетания как одну букву.

Задача №2:
Надо отсортировать слова в базе в соответствии с порядком кабардино-черкесского алфавита.

Я начинающий питонист и даже не знаю с какой стороны подойти к этой проблеме, поэтому прошу вашей помощи/совета, коллеги.

Comment: Наверно, хорошим решением будет предварительная "трансляция" слова к его сортируемому варианту. То есть в базе хранить два значения: само слово и его вариант где буквосочетания заменены одним символом. Сортировку производить по этому полю. Впрочем, дождитесь экспертов.

Comment: Разработать сортировщик, кодировщик для языка и внедрить во все стандарты. unicod-ы там всякие, locale. Тогда в новых версиях баз lfyys[ можно будет указать соответствующий locale, и всё само собой отсортируется.

Comment: Хорошая идея @ReinRaus, но учитывая, что в базе уже больше 4 тыс. слов надо найти способ автоматизировать этот процесс. Но начало есть, спасибо!

Comment: @Sergey, ну это, наверное, самый идеальный вариант, но мне как начинающему в эти дебри пока лезть не хотелось бы)

Comment: Посмотрите существует ли уже для кабардино-черкесского языка Unicode collator (вот пример для русского языка [`rank = icu.Collator.createInstance(icu.Locale('ru')).getSortKey`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446833/23044)). Если нет, то 1- разбейте входной текст на последовательность буквосочетаний (по аналогии с `regex.findall(r'\X', text)`) 2- напишите `rank` функцию, которая умеет сравнивать отдельные буквосочетания.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Пишется функция, которая разбирает строку на символы языка (буквосочетания)
2. Составляется словарь, в котором каждому символу языка сопоставляется его порядковый номер
3. Пишется функция, которая проходит по сравниваемым словам параллельно, разбирая на символы и сравнивает их номера из таблиц.

Код примерно такой:

```
def kab_cher_cmp(w1, w2):
  '''Функция сравнения слов для кабардино-черкесского языка
  @param w1: Первое слово
  @param w2: Второе слово
  @return: 0 - слова равны, <0 - первое раньше, >0 - второе раньше
  '''
  for c1, c2 in zip(kab_cher_smb(w1.lower()), kab_cher_smb(w2.lower())):
    if c1 == c2:
      continue
    return KAB_CHER_ORD[c1] - KAB_CHER_ORD[c2]
  return 0

KAB_CHER_ORD = {
  'а': 1, 'э': 2, 'б': 3, 'в': 4, 'г': 5, 'гу': 6, ...}
import re
_re_kab_cher_smb = re.compile('кхъу|хъу|кхъ|къу|кІу|....', re.I)

def kab_cher_smb(w):
  '''Функция разбора строки на символы кабардино-черкесского языка'''
  for m in _re_kab_cher_smb.finditer(w):
    yield m.group()
```

Для окончательного решения нужно понять, что делать в случае если попадётся символ не из кабардино-черкесского языка, например пробел или цифра. :)
Ну и в kab_cher_smb вместо регулярки можно использовать честный конечный автомат. :)