# Вывести ТОП 5 повторяющихся строк в тексте из файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

Доброго субботнего вечера. Вывести топ 5 пробовал через sorted и срез. Успеха - 0. Выводит всё что есть. Возможно какая-то ошибка в теле.

```
import re

slovo = {}
f = open('data_2.txt' ,'r')
file = f.read().lower()
pattern = re.findall(r'\b[a-z]{1,15}\b', file)
for word in pattern:
    count = slovo.get(word, 0)
    slovo[word] = count + 1
slovo_list = slovo.keys()
for words in slovo_list:
    print(f'"{words}" повторяется в тексте - {slovo[words]} раза/раз')
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/210480/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По вашему коду вы все-таки хотите найти топ-5 наиболее встречающихся **слов**, а не строк, в тексте файла.

Сделать это проще всего через `Counter`, достаточно передать ему список всех слов из файла, которые можно получить при помощи регулярного выражения, и вызвать функцию `most_common()`:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

with open('data.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()
    words = re.findall(r'[\w]+', data)
    result = Counter(words)
    print(result.most_common(5))
```

Comment: Супер. Теперь выходит так, что вывод в списке. И для конвертации использую map через join . Print("\n".join(map(str,result.most_common(5))))  А  вот пример того что ожидаю....
'list' - 5
'is' - 3
'a' - 3
'ul' - 3