# Проблемы с кодировкой Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.x, кодировка

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSRxH.jpg]

Как можно это исправить? Пробовал разные костыли, ничего не помогло

Comment: А что это такое? Или угадывание является часть вопроса?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Кракозябры указывают на то, что текст закодированный в одной кодировке показывается в другой (несовместимой кодировке):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print(u"Привет, мир!".encode('cp1251').decode('cp866')) #XXX: don't do it
# -> ╧ЁштхЄ, ьшЁ!
```

ANSI кодировка (`cp1251`), используемая в Windows, может  отличается от OEM кодировки (`cp866`), используемой в консоле с `cmd.exe`. Например, это может произойти, если прочитать текстовый файл, как бинарный  и вывести результат (последовательность байт) как есть.

Правильный подход: *считывать текст, используя `unicode` тип и печатать строго `unicode`* — пример в вопросе явно показывает почему не следует жёстко прописывать какую-либо кодировку — кодировка, которая работает в одном окружении, может перестать работать в другом.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import io

with io.open('input_file.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace(u"мир", u"Юникод"), end='')
```

`encoding='utf-8'` нужно заменить на действительную кодировку входного файла. Эта кодировка никак не связана с кодировкой исходного кода. Если кодировку не указать, то `io.open()` использует `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` (что-нибудь вроде `cp1251` на русской Винде).

Если кодировка неизвестна, то можно только гадать что файл содержит (хотя некоторые варианты могут быть более вероятны чем другие, см. [`chardet` модуль](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet)).

Если перенаправить вывод в файл, то необходимо установить `PYTHONIOENCODING` переменную окружения:

```
Z:\> set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
Z:\> python your_script.py >output-utf8.txt
```

Кодировку можно выбрать любую, которая поддерживает полный набор символов, которые могут быть напечатаны `your_script.py`.

Чтобы напечатать все Юникодные символы в консоль, даже те которые не могут быть представлены в текущей кодировке, используемой в консоле, можно использовать [win-unicode-console пакет](https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console) (идея состоит [в использовании `WriteConsoleW()` win32 API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3259271/4279)):

```
Z:\> py -mpip install win-unicode-console
Z:\> py -mrun your_script.py
```

Если выставить подходящий шрифт в окне консоли, то любые (BMP) Юникодные символы  можно увидеть (*независимо от текущей кодировки консоли*), а не только 256 символов, которые могут быть представлены в 8-битной кодировке такой как `cp866`.

Answer (score 5):

```
print u"Это текст"
print "Это текст".decode('utf-8')
```

Попробуй 2 эти варианта

Системную кодировку можно узнать через sys.stdout.encoding

Comment: Пробовал, с английскими буквами все норм, с русскими не работает

Answer (score 5):

Сразу после запуска командной строки выполните команду: chcp 1251

Comment: Не помогает, хотя по идее должно работать

Comment: Какая система установлена? Какая кодировка в системе по умолчанию?

Comment: Windows 7, кодировку не менял, наверное cp-1251