# Неразбериха в XHR response - "РѕСЂРё - Р”РѕРјР°"

Tags: html, python, ajax, кодировка

Как можно обработать **response XHR** , что бы спарсить информацию(Python), почему response  **"РѕСЂРё - Р”РѕРјР°"** , а браузер показыает информацию без "кракозябр"?

Comment: потому что Ваш код пытается декодировать текст в utf-8 как cp1251.

Comment: [похожий вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229015/23044): `u"РѕСЂРё - Р”РѕРјР°".encode('cp1251').decode('utf-8') == u'ори - Дома'`