# Python3: Символы \x90 \x8D \x8F \x8D \x81 в тексте с кодировкой cp1252

Tags: mysql, python, кодировка, python-3.x, utf-8

При получении данных из таблицы MySQL (используя Connector/Python) текстовые строки имеют вид:

> ÐšÐ°Ð»Ð°ÑˆÐ½Ð¸ÐºÐ¾Ð²Ð° Ð•Ð»ÐµÐ½Ð° Ð¡ÐµÑ€Ð³ÐµÐµÐ²Ð½Ð°

и

> Ð¢Ð¸Ñ‰ÐµÐ½ÐºÐ¾ Ð\x90Ð½Ð´Ñ€ÐµÐ¹ Ð’Ð°Ñ\x81Ð¸Ð»ÑŒÐµÐ²Ð¸Ñ‡

Декодер показывает, что это кодировка **CP1252**, поэтому в Python3 мы можем обработать их `str.encode('cp1252').decode('utf8')`, однако если этот метод работает для первой строки, то не работает для второй.

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x90' in position 16: character maps to undefined

Проблема - в специальных символах **\x90**, **\x9D**, **\x8F**, **\x8D**, **\x81**. В описании Windows-1252 указано, что эти коды относятся к C1 control codes.

Каким образом можно декодировать эти строки в Python3, не изменяя базу MySQL? Или где ещё может быть источник проблемы?

Comment: Вы уверены, что данные в базе записаны "правильно"? Проверяли сторонними утилитами?

Comment: А нельзя данные сразу в utf-8 читать?

Comment: попробуйте явно указать `charset` (*utf8*) при подключении к базе данных.

Comment: База - реально действующая, работающая. В программе, для которой она написана, всё отображается верно и кириллицей. При импорте данных получаю такие строки. Натыкался, что [подобное](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596786/fixing-incorrect-string-encoding-from-mysql) встречается, но решения на ruby не понял.

Comment: А можно вывод print(repr(строка))?

Comment: При `print(repr(str))` Получаются такие же результаты ровным счётом: `Ð¢Ð¸Ñ‰ÐµÐ½ÐºÐ¾ Ð\x90Ð½Ð´Ñ€ÐµÐ¹ Ð’Ð°Ñ\x81Ð¸Ð»ÑŒÐµÐ²Ð¸Ñ‡`    

Указывать явно кодировку базы при импорте пробовал - cp1252 в списке кодировок нет, utf8 даёт такой вот точно результат, что и описан.

Comment: Интересно, что `TABLE_COLLATION` у таблицы - `utf8_general_ci`, и консольный вывод в **mysql** `SELECT * FROM table_name` я получаю такими же *кракозябрами*. В то же время она прекрасно выводится кириллицей в программе, для которой написана. Загадка неживой природы)

Comment: @ilyinilyas, верноятно, в программе приделан по этому поводу «костыль».

Comment: Нашёл решение и уже написал ответ) Положился на декодер, и поверил, что там **cp1252**, хотя такой кодировки нет среди поддерживаемых MySQL.

Comment: похожий (часть про кракозябы) вопрос: [Проблемы с кодировкой Python 2.7](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229015/23044)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Нашёл ответ!)**
При импорте базы данных нужно использовать кодировку `latin1`
Тогда в Python3 для декодирования таких строк необходимо выполнить `str.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')`.
На решение натолкнула эта статья - [Solving Latin1 and UTF8 errors for good in Ruby](http://jalada.co.uk/2011/12/07/solving-latin1-and-utf8-errors-for-good-in-ruby.html):

> **Latin1** is a character encoding used by MySQL. People mistakenly think it is equivalent to **ISO-8859-1** but it isn’t, it’s actually **CP-1252** (also known as Windows-1252). **CP-1252** is a superset of **ISO-8859-1** with some additional characters (recently including the € symbol).

Соответcnвенно, я нашёл в [списке поддерживаемых кодировок](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html) `latin1`, и использовал её при подключении к MySQL с помощью Connector/Python.

Comment: Да уж, такую базу с такой программой по возможности крайне желательно перевести на нормальный utf-8

Comment: в тему: [What is the exact difference between Windows-1252(1/3/4) and ISO-8859-1?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19110555/4279)