# Как создать zip-архив и добавить в него случайные фотографии?

Tags: python

```
        file = ['photo/*.jpg']
        images = glob.glob(random.choice(file))
        random_img = random.choice(images)
        ima = [random_img]
    inpt = ima
    # prefix path
    pre = None
    oupt = f'zip/{message.from_user.id}.zip'
    # set password value
    create_password = random.randbytes(20)
    # compress level
    com_lvl = 5
    pyminizip.compress_multiple(inpt, None, oupt, create_password, com_lvl)
```

Но компилятор выдает ошибку:

```
ValueError: expected arguments are compress_multiple(srcfiles, prefixs, zipfile, password, compress_level, progress)
```

Comment: Если вы будете плодить однотипные вопросы, я буду закрывать их как дубликаты. Читайте документацию. И не "компилятор", а "интерпретатор".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша программа генерирует пароли как последовательность битов, поэтому программа будет воспринимать данный пароль как объект типа `bytes`:

```py
h = random.randbytes(20)
print(type(h)) # <class 'bytes'>
```

**Однако**, если верить [документации pyminizip](https://pypi.org/project/pyminizip/), функция `compress_multiple` поддерживает следующие элементы:

1. src file LIST path (list)
2. *src file LIST prefix path (list) or []*
3. dst file path (string)
4. password (***string***) or None (to create no-password zip)
5. compress_level(int) between 1 to 9, 1 (more fast) <---> 9 (more compress)
6. optional function to be called during processing which takes one argument, the count of how many files have been compressed

Иными словами, пароль должен подаваться как **строка**, но не как последовательность битов. Из-за этого и происходит ошибка нераспознавания значений.

Отдельно отмечу второй пункт, в котором можно подавать список либо с чем-то, либо пустой `[]`, но не `None`. Это тоже не даёт нормально запустить функцию.

Поэтому необходимо сгенерированную последовательность битов преобразовать в строку (см. [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12073686), берётся последовательность битов, каждый из них обращается в символ, и все вместе они образуют строку), а вместо `None` во втором аргументе передать `[]`:

```py
file = ['photo/*.jpg']
images = glob.glob(random.choice(file))
random_img = random.choice(images)
ima = [random_img]
inpt = ima
# prefix path
pre = None
oupt = f'zip/{message.from_user.id}.zip'
# set password value
byte_password = random.randbytes(20)
create_password = "".join(map(chr, byte_password)) # 1
# compress level
com_lvl = 5
pyminizip.compress_multiple(inpt, [], oupt, create_password, com_lvl) # 2
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за разъяснение

Comment: я прогоняю через for столько раз сколько сгенерирует rand_photo, но в архиве все равно одно фото: for i in range(rand_photo):
        file = ['photo/*.jpg']
        images = glob.glob(random.choice(file))
        random_img = random.choice(images)
        ima = [random_img]
        inpt = ima
        # prefix path
        pre = None
        oupt = f'zip/{message.from_user.id}.zip'
        # set password value
        byte_password = random.randbytes(20)
        create_password = "".join(map(chr, byte_password)) # 1
        # compress level
        com_lvl = 5

Comment: @SlimThugs `ima.append(random_img)` должен добавлять внутри цикла рандомную фотографию, потому что Вы постоянно перезаписываете `ima` каждую итерацию цикла

Comment: то есть мне нужно ?

Comment: @SlimThugs Вам нужно заменить `ima = [random_img]` на `ima.append(random_img)`, чтобы не перезаписывать список изображений, и добавлять туда новые

Comment: visual code желтым выделяет

Comment: @SlimThugs что выделает жёлтым и как это отражается на работоспособности программы?

Comment: ima выделяется желтым

Comment: name 'ima' is not defined

Comment: @SlimThugs тогда до самого цикла определите `ima = []` — как пустой список

Comment: Все хорошо заработало, теперь всегда разное количество фоток. И еще вопрос: как очищать список ?

Comment: @SlimThugs `ima = []` либо `ima.clear()` (https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/clear)

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: я создаю txt файл: fi_pass = open(f'pass/{message.from_user.id}.txt','w') Потом записываю в файл: fi_pass.write(create_password) Выдает ошибку 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x90' in position 3: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Добавил create_password.encode("utf-8") но ничего не изменилось

Comment: @SlimThugs https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432777 — здесь предлагают сначала кодировать в `latin1`, а затем в `utf-8`

Comment: Кстати да, вопросы, не относящиеся к данному, лучше всего публиковать отдельными постами, а не в комментариях

Comment: Я хотел в чат, но не дает

Comment: Добавил create_password.encode('latin1').decode('utf8') выдает 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 3: invalid continuation byte

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1376172/Как-декодировать-пароль