# Кодировка в python 3

Tags: python, windows, кодировка, python-3.x, odbc

Подключение к базе данных (*Pervasive*).

Кодировка базы - *cp866*. ОС - *Windows*

Не могу вывести в консоль кириллицу.

```
import pyodbc
dbfile = pyodbc.connect('DSN=test')
cursor = dbfile.cursor()
cursor.execute("select NameAccount from account_dbt")
row = cursor.fetchall()
for l in range(4):
    t = str(row[l][0])
    print(t)
```

Результат:

```
ЋЋЋ ђ®¬ иЄ  Ћ¤Ё­(Romashka odin)
ЋЋЋ ђ®¬ иЄ  Ћ¤Ё­(Romashka odin) - 2
ЋЋЋ ђ®¬ иЄ  Ћ¤Ё­(Romashka odin) - 3
ЋЋЋ ђ®¬ иЄ  Ћ¤Ё­(Romashka odin) - 4
```

Пробовал так:

```
t = str(row[l][0]).encode('utf-8')
```

Результат:

```
b'\xd0\x8b\xd0\x8b\xd0\x8b \xd1\x92\xc2\xae\xc2\xac\xc2\xa0\xd0\xb8\xd0\x84\xc2\xa0 \xd0\x8b\xc2\xa4\xd0\x81\xc2\xad(Romashka odin)'
b'\xd0\x8b\xd0\x8b\xd0\x8b \xd1\x92\xc2\xae\xc2\xac\xc2\xa0\xd0\xb8\xd0\x84\xc2\xa0 \xd0\x8b\xc2\xa4\xd0\x81\xc2\xad(Romashka odin) - 2'
b'\xd0\x8b\xd0\x8b\xd0\x8b \xd1\x92\xc2\xae\xc2\xac\xc2\xa0\xd0\xb8\xd0\x84\xc2\xa0 \xd0\x8b\xc2\xa4\xd0\x81\xc2\xad(Romashka odin) - 3'
b'\xd0\x8b\xd0\x8b\xd0\x8b \xd1\x92\xc2\xae\xc2\xac\xc2\xa0\xd0\xb8\xd0\x84\xc2\xa0 \xd0\x8b\xc2\xa4\xd0\x81\xc2\xad(Romashka odin) - 4'
```

Статья на хабре про кодировки тоже не внесла ясность.

Как отобразить текст в читабельном виде?

Comment: попробуйте [указать charset](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9983149/4827341). не знаю, как это интерпретируется кодом pyodbc, поэтому я бы сначала попробовал указать *utf8*, и, если это не приведёт к каким-то визуальным изменениям, то *cp866* (или как оно должно правильно называться в используемой вами операционной системе).

Comment: @alexander barakin, указывал при подключении и _UTF8_ и _CP866_. Результат тот же.

Comment: если пробовали, тогда, мне кажется, стоит об этом явно упомянуть в тексте вопроса.

Comment: Windows, Linux? Не знаю насчёт Linux, но у Windows весьма своебразная консоль у которой свои счёты с кодировками. Попробуйте для начала вывести в файл, чтобы понять когда код работает правильно. После этого терзайте уже консоль. Копайте  в сторону команды CHCP. Мое решение в Python2 было совсем страшное: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878972/windows-cmd-encoding-change-causes-python-crash/3259271#3259271 и вот это ещё можете глянуть: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109024/how-to-make-unicode-charset-in-cmd-exe-by-default

Comment: Ваше решение либо неверное, либо неправильно понято. По крайней мере, вы в нем делаете совершенно не то, что объясняете.

Comment: Прошу прощения. Поправил.

Comment: не следует ответ на вопрос помещать в сам вопрос. Опубликуйте его как ответ (чтобы можно было голосовать, комментировать и т.д.)

Comment: [про кракозябы и как Юникод можно в Виндовую консоль вывести (`py -mrun`)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/414060/23044)

Comment: не следует `str()` использовать без надобности. Что `print(ascii(row[l][0]))` показывает?

Comment: @jfs, Вот вывод:    
''\u040b\u040b\u040b \u0452\xae\xac\xa0\u0438\u0404\xa0 \u040b\xa4\u0401\xad(Romashka odin)''

Comment: да, действительно проблема в том что текст закодированный с помощью cp866 интерпретируется с помощью неверной для него cp1251 кодировки (`locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`?) и `rows = [row.encode('mbcs').decode('cp866') for row in cursor.fetchall()]` позволяет обойти проблему. По-хорошему следует узнать на каком этапе cp1251 применяется (добавляются ли уже неверные данные в базу данных или только при извлечении из базы портятся (попробовать настройки  соединения (кодировку) изменить)).

Answer (score 1):

Решение:

```
t = str(row[l][0]).encode('cp1251'), encoding='cp866')
```

Сначала строка `row[l][0]` переводится в байтовую строку в кодировке cp1251, а потом в обычную строку в кодировке cp1251.