# Как выводить принт на русском Python/PyCharm?

Tags: python, utf-8, кодировка, pycharm

```
# coding: utf-8
print "Привет мир!"

вывод: РџСЂРёРІРµС‚ РјРёСЂ!
```

Comment: http://torofimofu.fvds.ru/learnwithpython/ru2e/app_a_russian.html

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблемы с кодировкой Python 2.7](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/229015/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-python-2-7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот собственно вырезка из статьи:

> Чтобы сообщить Python о том, что скрипт использует кодировку, отличную
>   от ASCII, нужно в начале файла поместить комментарий специального
>   вида, содержащий информацию о кодировке файла. Для скрипта russian.py,
>   созданного в Блокноте, укажем кодировку cp1251, после чего скрипт
>   будет выглядеть так:

```
> # -*- coding: cp1251 -*-
> 
> `print 'Привет мир!'`
```

После этого сможем успешно выполнить скрипт в

> консольном окне Windows (только не забудьте установить текущую
>   кодировку командой chcp 1251):

```
> C:\>chcp 1251 Active code page: 1251
> 
> C:\>python russian.py Привет мир!
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @DenisBoiko: `coding: cp1251` + `chcp 1251`  это плохое решение.  Оставьте `coding: utf-8` как есть, не вызывайте `chcp 1251`, не печатайте текст как байты, а используйте Юникод `u"Привет мир!"` вместо этого (обратите внимание на `u''` префикс). Чтобы напечатать текст с произвольными Юникодными символами см., [мой ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/414060/23044)