# Байты - перевод из строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

```
data = "Hello".encode("utf-8") # перевод в байты
```

не могу разобраться в байтах... как бы я не старался, `Python` мне выдает `b'Hello'`... как мне получить исходные байты этой строки?

Если попробовать с кириллицей, то все получается:

```
data = "Привет".encode("utf-8") # b'\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'
```

или я не имею представления о байтах?  объясните пожалуйста

Comment: Ну вот `Hello` это и есть байты, а `\xNN` это шестнадцеричные коды этих байтов. так что для их получения надо использовать функции получающие эти коды, во многих языках такая функция зовется `ord`, как в питоне хз, Собственно запрос гуглу "python ord" дает пищу для размышлений. А encode судя по названию просто кодирует в \xNN символы которые необходимо кодировать, а латинские символы такими не являются.

Comment: @Mike : `data` уже имеет тип `bytes`, который в Питоне является неизменяемой последовательностью байтов: `data[0]` это первый байт (`72 == 0x48` обычное целое число как правило в диапазоне 0..255 (октет)). `b'Hello'` — это просто синтаксис для констант типа `bytes`, который можно в исходном коде использовать и совпадает с текстовым представлением (`eval(repr(data)) == data`). ASCII символы могут быть использованы в bytes-константах, чтобы представить соответсвующие байты `b'\x48\x65' == b'He'`.

Comment: @jfs Тогда я не понимаю почему ТС не воспользуется обычной ротацией которая у него и так написана

Comment: @Mike: `s/ротацией/нотацией/`. OP поэтому и спросил: *«или не имею представления о байтах»*. `data` уже является байтами—ничего не нужно дальше делать.  Байты это настолько фундаментальная абстракция, что тяжело сперва понять, что они являются обычными объектами как и всё остальное в Питоне. See [How to open and present raw binary data in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33145337/4279)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как `b'Hello'` так и `b'\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80...'` принадлежат к одному типу `bytes`.

`b'Hello' == b'\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f'`. Байты, которые соответствуют печатаемым ascii символам (`0x20..0x7e`), по умолчанию показаны как эти символы в текстовом представлении `repr(data)` -- синтаксис, используемый для bytes-конcтант в исходном коде Питона (`eval(repr(data)) == data`).

Использование символов для некоторых байтов вместо шестнадцатеричных кодов может вводить в заблуждение (как в этом случае). Легко [получить hexdump, если необходимо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/497066/23044):

```
>>> b'Hello'.hex()
'48656c6c6f'
```

Мотивация по использованию `b'Hello'` вместо `b'\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f'` могла быть связана с тем, что многие популярные протоколы такие как HTTP свободно смешивают текст (закодированный в ascii-совместимой кодировке) и двоичные данные. Поэтому использование символов вместо hex-кодов может помочь при отладке.

Недостаток использования `b'Hello'` вместо `b'\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f'` состоит в том что люди смешивают понятия текста (Юникодные строки) и двоичных данных (байтов), что ведёт к путанице и в итоге [мусору (кракозябрам) в результатах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229015/23044). Что было особенно остро на Питоне 2, где `str = bytes`. See [Stop displaying elements of bytes objects as printable ASCII characters in CPython 3 [python-ideas mailing list (2014)]](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.ideas/29242/).

Без явного указания кодировки, последовательность байтов (`bytes` объект) является просто набором чисел. Последовательность байтов становится текстом только, если байты декодированы, используя подходящую кодировку:

```
unicode_text = bytestring.decode(character_encoding)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это. Функция `ord` вернет значение символа в десятеричном коде:

```
text = "Hello world!"
[(c, ord(c), hex(ord(c))) for c in text]
```

Результат:

```
[('H', 72, '0x48'), ('e', 101, '0x65'), ('l', 108, '0x6c'), 
('l', 108, '0x6c'), ('o', 111, '0x6f'), (' ', 32, '0x20'), 
('w', 119, '0x77'), ('o', 111, '0x6f'), ('r', 114, '0x72'), 
('l', 108, '0x6c'), ('d', 100, '0x64'), ('!', 33, '0x21')]
```

Comment: Ответ только запутывает. Автор вопроса использует Питон 3. `text` в вашем примере является Юникодной строкой в Питон 3 — последовательностью Юникодных символов (Unicode codepoints).  `ord(c)` возвращает номер символа. Исторически первые Юникодные символы упорядочены также как в ASCII (по дизайну) поэтому номера совпадают с соответствующими байтами. bytes уже является последовательностью байтов (`int`) — не нужно `ord()` вызывать.

Comment: Так `list(map(int, 'вася'.encode()))`?

Comment: нет. *"bytes уже является последовательностью байтов (`int`)"*. Ничего не нужно вызывать, например, `b = data[i]` или `for b in data` работают как есть.