# Перевод массива байтов в hex строку C# & Python

Tags: c#, python, массивы, python-3.x, строки

Есть код на C#:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
{
    result += string.Format("0x{0:x2} ", bytes[i]);
}
```

По моим предположениям, на Python это должно выглядеть так:

```
for i in bytes:
    result += '0x{} '.join(i)
```

Но, работает неверно. В чём ошибка? И как на Python осуществить форматирование, которое используется выше в коде на C#?

Comment: related: [What's the correct way to convert bytes to a hex string in Python 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6624453/4279)

Comment: не следует изменять вопрос таким образом, что делает существующие ответы неверными. Если у вас новый вопрос (как сделать на Питоне 2, а не 3), то задайте его как новый вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение было обнаружено вот тут: [Bytes to hex representation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20726001/3844702).

Исправленный код на Python выглядит так:

```
for i in bytes:
    result += '0x{} '.format(i.encode('hex'))
```

Comment: `.encode('hex')` не будет работать на Питоне 3 (у Вас вопрос помечен тагом python-3.x).

Comment: Многократный вызов `s +=`  чреват `O(n**2)` квадратичным поведением для строк. В CPython есть оптимизация, которая приводит к линейному алгоритму, но не стоит на неё в общем случае полагаться (небольшие изменения в коде могут её выключить). Вместо этого можно использовать `''.join` как показано в других ответах.

Answer (score 2):

`bytes` это встроенное имя в Питоне, поэтому его следует избегать для частных имён. Обзовём входные данные как `data`. Тогда чтобы конвертировать в шестнадцатеричное представление, можно использовать `data.hex()` вызов доступный в Питоне 3.5:

```
>>> b'abc'.hex()
'616263'
```

На более ранних версиях, можно использовать `binascii.hexlify(data).decode()`:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(b'abc')
b'616263'
```

Если хочется получить `0x` перед каждым байтом в Питоне 3:

```
>>> ' '.join(['0x%02x' % b for b in b'abc'])
'0x61 0x62 0x63'
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю лучшее решение (при условии что bytes - массив чисел):

```
result = ''.join('%02x '%i for i in bytes)
```

Comment: "bytes" - массив байтов. Требовалось на выходе получить строку определённого вида. Представленное ниже решение удовлетворяет требованиям к виду строки: 0x32 0xd4 0x5a ...