# Необходимо цифровую подпись RSA+SHA1 предоставить в формате HEX, С#

Tags: c#, hex, цифровая-подпись

Необходимо результат RSA+SHA1 (строка 7B-87-5A-32...) предоставить в формате HEX.
Не понимаю, как это сделать и что из себя это должно представлять?
На форумах вычитал, что нужно просто исключить "-" и всё, правильно ли это?

Необходимо конечное значение отправить в теге XML документа.
Грубо говоря, когда идет преобразование в строку из Byte[] - получается 7B-87-5A-32... и сервер на это ругается, что формат ЭЦП не тот.
В API написано:

> Полученное значение подписи помещается в тег sig в формате HEX.

Соответственно, если убрать все "-" - то сервер принимает данный формат, но пишет, что не верна подпись.

```
var enc = rsa.Encrypt(ByteForEncode_, false);
var signature = rsa.SignData(enc, "SHA1");
string StrSigOut = BitConverter.ToString(signature).Replace("-", ""); // в формате HEX??
xml_text = xml_text + "<rsb_ns:sig>" + StrSigOut + "</rsb_ns:sig>";
```

Comment: Да зачем вам строка, преобразования? Запишите просто `var key = new byte[] {0x7B, 0x78,0x5A,0x32, ...}` и не мучайтесь. Среда сама преобразует.

Comment: Если вопрос "Как преобразовать строку с hex в массив байт" то так и напишите, потому что преобразования не имеют отношения к цифровой подписи.

Comment: Вот ответ (влада) вам подойдёт https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420019/c-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2 только пробел на черточку поменяете.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [C#: преобразовать строку в массив байтов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420019/c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: @nick_n_a, апдейтнул вопрос, тут проблема обратная, из строки в HEX формат, а не наоборот

Comment: Тут на формуме и обратно есть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496905/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-hex-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-c-python просто в гугле вопрос наберите.

Comment: Приведите пожалуй кусок кода с преобразованиями.

Comment: Что-то я не понимаю. Проблема в преобразовании или в некорректности подписи?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов , вопрос в том, верно ли преобразование методом удаления "-"

Comment: @nick_n_a добавил код в вопрос

Comment: Без данных и ключа, IMHO, не проверить правильно вы подписываете или нет

Answer (score 0):

Когда идет преобразование в строку из Byte[] - получается "7B-87-5A-32..."
Для выполнения условия "Полученное значение подписи помещается в тег sig в формате HEX." - нужно просто исключить "-", например:
`//...
var hexString = BitConverter.ToString(data); // data - конечная строка (подпись в формате "7B-87-5A-32...")
hexString = hexString.Replace("-", ""); // и после этого пункта уже вписывать в тег
//...`

Comment: А какой тип имеет data? `Byte[]`?

Comment: Исходя из ответа, заголовок вопроса должен содержать фразу *перевод массива byte в hex строку*.