# Создание бинарного кода в Python 3.5 с помощью hex

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я новичок в питоне, поэтому вопрос может быть глупым, но все же,

```
hexOutput = main(hexLine)  
new.write(hexOutput.encode("hex"))
```

Данные строки в версии 2.7 работали без ошибок, но теперь выдает вот это:

> 'hex' is not a text encoding; use codecs.encode() to handle arbitrary codecs

Как нужно исправить ошибку?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Байты - перевод из строки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/496420/23044)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.7:

```
>>> b"abc".encode('hex')
'616263'
```

Python 3.5:

```
>>> b"abc".hex()
'616263'
```

Python 2/3:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(b'abc')
'616263'
```

Не путайте сами двоичные данные, к примеру последовательность байт: 97, 98, 99 и их текстовое представление в шестнадцатиричной системе `'616263'` так как 97<sub>10</sub> == 61<sub>16</sub> итд.

В Питоне 3:

```
>>> b'a'[0] == 97 == 0x61 == 0b01100001
True
```

---

Если вы хотите и другие подобные Python 2  `str.encode()` преобразования из str в str поддерживать, то можно `codecs` модуль использовать как в Питон 2 так и 3—как сообщение об ошибке рекомендует:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.encode('abc', 'rot13').encode()
b'nop'
>>> codecs.encode(_, 'zip')
b'x\x9c\xcb\xcb/\x00\x00\x02\x9b\x01N'
>>> codecs.encode(_, 'hex')
b'789ccbcb2f0000029b014e'
```

`bytes.encode()` убран в Питоне 3, чтобы подчеркнуть отличия от str типа (Unicode в Питоне 3) и исключить ошибки, связанные с неявным преобразованием байт в Unicode текст и обратно.