# Мистика в python 3 или модуль pyserial сошёл с ума

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, ascii

Здравствуйте. Происходит какая-то мистика в python 3, имеется  программа которая получает данные с com порта), формат данных такой: `b'#1F002EF414C\r'`. Нужно, эти данные занести в массив, что бы каждое число было на своей позиций. Должно получиться так [#][1][F] и т.п. Но вместо этих данных я получаю, вот это:

```
[35]
[35, 49]
[35, 49, 70]
[35, 49, 70, 48]
[35, 49, 70, 48, 48]
[35, 49, 70, 48, 48, 50]
[35, 49, 70, 48, 48, 50, 69]
[35, 49, 70, 48, 48, 50, 69, 70]
[35, 49, 70, 48, 48, 50, 69, 70, 52]
[35, 49, 70, 48, 48, 50, 69, 70, 52, 49]
[35, 49, 70, 48, 48, 50, 69, 70, 52, 49, 52]
[35, 49, 70, 48, 48, 50, 69, 70, 52, 49, 52, 67]
[35, 49, 70, 48, 48, 50, 69, 70, 52, 49, 52, 67, 13]
```

в python 2.7 все работает идеально) но в python 3, что-то мистическое. Я понял, что это почему то код ASCII и если добавить `unchar` то данные будут какие нужно. Но что с массивом, почему он выглядит именно так и почему заноситься код ASCII. помогите исправить массив(list) и разобраться)).
Код программы:

```
# coding: utf8 -*-
import serial

class ComPort:
    def Comport(self):
        global idnumbercard
        global ID
        forchar = 0
        idcom = []
        idcomstr = ""

        try:
            ser = serial.Serial(
                port = 'COM8',\
                baudrate=2400,\
                parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
                stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
                bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
                    timeout=None)
        except serial.SerialException:
            print('неверный com port')

        print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)
        count=1

        for line in ser.read(13):
            #forchar = forchar + 1
            idcom.append(line)
            print(idcom)
```

Comment: Потому что в 3 намутили со строками. Вы получаете код символа вместо символа. Я -- хейтер питона 3+, не помогу вам ;)

Comment: @Diq, вы смотрели, что возвращает print line ? Стоит посмотреть, если там летят строки, то наверно лучше будет list(line) использовать, кстати в 3.5 появилась такая возможность [*line], а если числа, то тут уже от ситуации зависит, можно по коду символа, вернуть сам символ и добавить в лист.

Comment: @And Спасибо) ваш ответ очень помог)) использую так в цикле `idcom.append(list(unichr(line)))`

Answer (score 3):

> Нужно, эти данные занести в массив, что бы каждое число было на своей позиций.

`b'#1F002EF414C\r'` уже является последовательностью байтов (чисел). Ничего делать не надо—вы уже можете по индексу обращаться к байтам (`data[i]`).

К сожалению, по умолчанию текстовое представление  байт (bytes тип) в ascii диапазоне выглядит как соответствующий ascii символ (текст). Например, `35` (байт, `23` в hex) показан как `'#'` символ, `49` показан как `'1'` (`31` в hex) `13` (`0D` в hex) показан как `'\r'`

```
>>> b'#1\r'.hex()
'23310d'
```

Представление двоичных данных в виде ascii символов вместо шестнадцатеричных кодов  может вводить в заблуждение (байт это число, а не символ--текст можно закодировать в виде байт, используя какую-нибудь кодировку, то есть последовательность байт может *представлять* текст, но сам байт не является текстом). Хотя оно может быть полезно для отладки протоколов, где текст в ascii-based кодировке и двоичные данные в перемежку могут идти, к примеру в HTTP протоколе).

Если вы вместо байта (числа), хотите получить при индексации объект типа bytes (последовательность байт) с длиной 1:

```
>>> data = b'#1\r'    
>>> [data[i:i+1] for i in range(len(data))]
[b'#', b'1', b'\r']
```

- [Байты - перевод из строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/496420/23044)
- [iterate over individual bytes in python3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14267452/4279)