# передать значение из str в hex

Tags: python, python-3.x

Стоит задача на входе у скрипта 16ричный код (`"7200F40004226301"`). Этот код в переменную считывается в формате list, и каждый символ имеет расширение как str, И необходимо что-бы скрипт мог с символом работать,как с числом.

```
for item in content: 
  for symbol in item: 
      k = int(''.join("%02X " % ord( symbol )))
```

результат:

```
>> symbol
7
>>> type(symbol)
<class 'str'>
>>> type(k)
<class 'int'>
>>> k
37
>>> hex(k)
'0x25'
```

Но я хочу сделать чтобы `hex(k) = 0x07`, а не `0x25`. 
Возможно я изначально неправильно выбрал путь решения задачи, так как профан в программировании.

Comment: передать что, куда?

Comment: я разобрал эту строку посимвольно и мне надо дать понять питону, что каждый символ уже в 16 ричном формате

Comment: В питоне нет типа числа в 16-ричной системе счисления. Эти числа представляются в виде строки, начинающейся с `0x`.

Comment: Покажите результат: `print(ascii(ваша_строка))`. Что вы хотите получить в результате (тип, значение)? Явно пример ввода вывода, используя Питон синтаксис покажите.

Comment: `int("0x" + str, 16)` ? Даже 0x в принципе не нужен. Потом разбирайте как хотите это число.

Comment: О, `from binascii import unhexlify`

Comment: @jfs Результат команды 'print(ascii(ваша_строка))':  '['7200440004226301', '5F0044000445F701',...]'. 
'for item in content:
    for symbol in item:
        k = int(''.join("%02X " % ord( symbol )))' 
Этот фрагмент кода разбирает каждый символ на десятичные значения, выводя значения symbol и k получается следующее: 
symbol: 7  
type(symbol):  <class 'str'>  
type(k):  <class 'int'>  
k:  37  
hex(k):  0x25.  
И я хочу сделать чтобы 'hex(k) = 0x07', а не '0x25'. 
Возможно я изначально неправильно выбрал путь решения задачи, так как профан в программировании.

Comment: Ну можно миллион решений придумать. Если вам полубайты хочется так получать (кстати, у вас big или little endiannes?), так даже в лоб можно сделать: `i = int(xstr, 16); while i: print("%x" % i & 0xf); i = i >> 4`. И поставьте себе `ipython`, будет легче жить.

Comment: @0andriy мне совсем не хочется их получать. Мне по факту из файла надо считать эти коды проанализировать, заменить определённые символы и поместить в конечный файл. Для чего это делается? Потому что СКУД не может работать с разными ключами и надо привести к одному виду.

Comment: @0andriy 'i = int(xstr, 16);' - это подходит =) ! Спасибо большое! Буду дальше писать скрипт

Comment: Яснее от комментария не стало. Если вы читаете из файла и пишите в файл изменённое содержимое, то покажите несколько байтов из входного файла и на какие байты и по какому правилу вы их хотите заменить. Не помещайте информацию необходимую для ответа в комментарии, отредактируйте ваш вопрос вместо этого (и код с нормальным форматированием добавьте). Если думаете что нашли решение, то опубликуйте его как свой ответ—[это явно приветствуется](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Возможно вам binascii.unhexlify() поможет.

Comment: @jfs да судя по всему человек учиться писать код, скорее всего ему просто надо аккуратнее сформулировать задачу.

Comment: Вы правы! Это моя первая задача. Спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если открыв файл как текст (к примеру, в notepad), вы видите в нём строку `7200F40004226301` (шестнадцатеричные цифры в тексте—Unicode символы: `7` ([U+0037 DIGIT SEVEN](http://codepoints.net/U+37)), `2` ([U+0032 DIGIT TWO](http://codepoints.net/U+32)), `0` ([U+0030 DIGIT ZERO](http://codepoints.net/U+30)), итд) так называемый [hexdump (bytes -> hex)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump), то чтобы выполнить обратное преобразование (hex -> bytes) и получить исходную последовательность байт: 0x72, 0x00, 0xF4, ... как тип `bytes` в Питоне:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.unhexlify("7200F40004226301")  # из hex-строки в bytes
b'r\x00\xf4\x00\x04"c\x01'
>>> list(_)
[114, 0, 244, 0, 4, 34, 99, 1]
>>> b'r'[0]  # индексация bytes возвращает индивидуальные байты (int)
114
>>> int("72", 16)  # из hex-строки в int
114
>>> 0x72 == 114 == 0b1110010  # одно и то же число в разных системах исчисления
True
```

В тексте Питон программы, байты, которые соответствуют печатаемым ASCII символам, могут быть представлены как эти символы, поэтому байт `114` печатается в виде текста как `b'r'`, а не `b'\x72'` как другие байты. См. [Байты - перевод из строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/496420/23044).

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то на входе вы получаете кодированные в hex бинарные данные.
Для получения байтового массива из такого представления есть функция [binascii.unhexlify](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify%20binascii.unhexlify)