# Кракозябры при записи в файл скаченной html страницы

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, кодировка, requests

Когда я качаю и сохраняю файл, у меня выводит некие символы типа "\x80\xe2\x94\x80\xe2\x94\x80".

Как я понял, тут проблема с кодировкой. Как это можно исправить? Заранее спасибо.

```
import requests
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'
}

url = 'https://ru.dotabuff.com/players/415673590/matches/' 
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

with open('test.html', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write(str(r.text.encode('UTF8')))
```

Comment: `.write(r.text)` и всё, зачем всё усложнять-то

Comment: А вообще какая у вас версия питона?

Comment: @andreymal `write(r.text)` может несогласованное содержимое создать: `<meta charset`  может одно говорить, а фактическая кодировка файла, определяемая `locale.getpreferredencoding()` другое. Лучше как есть content в 'wb' режиме сохранять, если кодировка в html указана. Поэтому beautifulsoup4 умеет переписывать соответсвующие элементы (для случаев когда хочется поменять кодировку или когда кодировка в http заголовках, а не самом содержимом прописана) в prettify(), encode() методах — в итоге самосогласованное содержимое на диске: html записан на диск в указанной в нём кодировке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\xe2\x94\x80` — это текстовое представление байт в Питоне. [Байты - перевод из строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/496420/23044):

```
>>> '\u2500'.encode()
b'\xe2\x94\x80'
```

то есть байты: `226`, `148`, `128` записаны, используя экранирующие последовательности ascii символов `\ x h h`: `\xe2`, `\x94`, `\x80` (т.к. 226<sub>10</sub> = e2<sub>16</sub>, 148<sub>10</sub> = 94<sub>16</sub>, 128<sub>10</sub> = 80<sub>16</sub>).

[`─` (U+2500) символ](http://codepoints.net/U+2500) кодируется в utf-8 кодировке последовательностью октетов: 226, 148, 128.

Вы их видите как `\xe2\x94\x80` из-за `str(text.encode())` в коде в вопросе (это ошибка, не следует так делать). Текстовое представление байт (repr) полезно при отладке. На диск следует писать либо сами байты (файл должен быть открыт в двоичном режиме: `'wb'`) как показано в [@gil9red ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/764722/23044), либо использовать текстовый интерфейс (`'w'` режим и подходящий для документа encoding параметр).

Чтобы гарантировать, что html записан на диск в utf-8 кодировке [в самосогласованном виде](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/764705/%d0%9a%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b7%d1%8f%d0%b1%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-html-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b#comment1188443_764705) вне зависимости в какой кодировке сайт возвращает html, [можно BeautifulSoup использовать](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-encoding).

В вашем случае, сайт уже html в виде utf-8 возвращает и в самом содержимом `<meta` элемент c `Content-Type` это подтверждает, поэтому достаточно `Path('test.html').write_bytes(r.content)` вариант использовать.

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется лучшим вариантом сохранить данные без преобразования кодировок. Для этого открываем файл в бинарном режиме и записываем байтовый массив html страницы:

```
with open('test.html', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```