# Перекодировать байтовые строки, находящиеся внутри xml

Tags: python, xml, строки, кодировка, soap

Мне нужно исследовать работу с одной системной, общение с которой проходит через SOAP. Система возвращает документы с текстовой информацией о них. Нужно изучить, насколько хорошо система работает с кириллицей.

В ответ на запросы приходят такие респонсы:

```
b'<?xml version="1.0"?>\r\n<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><NS1:GetBlockResponse xmlns:NS1="SysEtranInt"><return xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</return><Text xsi:type="xsd:string">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?&gt;\r\n&lt;error&gt;\r\n&lt;errorCode value="2"/&gt;\r\n&lt;errorMessage value="\xd0\x9d\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb9 \xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81 &amp;quot;!--&amp;quot;"/&gt;\r\n&lt;errorStatusCode value="406"/&gt;\r\n&lt;/error&gt;\r\n</Text></NS1:GetBlockResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'
```

Запросы делаю на питоне при помощи библиотеки zeep.

Строки приходят в виде байтовых строк:`value="\xd0\x9d\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb9`. Как их можно перекодировать в читаемый текст?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Кракозябры при записи в файл скаченной html страницы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/764705/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше поискать библиотеки для работы с `SOAP`, но т.к. это просто `XML`, то можно и соответствующей библиотекой попарсить, например `BeautifulSoup`:

```
rs_xml = b'<?xml version="1.0"?>\r\n<SOAP-ENV:Envelope ...'

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
root = BeautifulSoup(rs_xml, 'html.parser')

# print(root)
# print('\n')

data_xml = root.select_one('text').text

root = BeautifulSoup(data_xml, 'html.parser')
print(root)
print(root.select_one('errormessage')['value'])
```

Результат:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?><html><body><error>
<errorcode value="2"></errorcode>
<errormessage value='Неизвестный запрос "!--"'></errormessage>
<errorstatuscode value="406"></errorstatuscode>
</error>
</body></html>
Неизвестный запрос "!--"
```

---

`BeautifulSoup` берет парсер `html.parser` из стандартного модуля: https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html

[Примеры использования парсеров](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser), например:

- Python’s html.parser: `BeautifulSoup(markup, "html.parser")`
- lxml’s HTML parser: `BeautifulSoup(markup, "lxml")`
- lxml’s XML parser: `BeautifulSoup(markup, "lxml-xml")` или `BeautifulSoup(markup, "xml")`
- html5lib: `BeautifulSoup(markup, "html5lib")`

Comment: для xml можно ElementTree из стандартной библиотеки использовать. А автор просто не знает как текстовое представление bytes в Питоне выглядит [Байты - перевод из строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/496420/23044)

Comment: Можно, но я, каюсь, поленился и пошел по пути наименьшего сопротивления :)