# Как открыть файл, чтобы содержимое было в 16-ричном виде

Tags: python

Если открыть файл обычным методом open, то содержимое показывается в кодировке utf-8 (насколько я понял - C\xb0\xcc\x00\xd6\xd2\xd4X\xb2\xac-\xd7VU...).
Мне очень не удобно работать с этим форматом.

К примеру sublime text 3 (текстовый редактор), при открытии, к примеру, файла с расширением .exe (и др...), показывает код, очень похожий на 16-ричный (Пример открытия mp3 файла - 4944 3304 0000 0000 0776 5443 4f4e 0000 0005 0000 003f 3f3f 3f54). Т.к как бинарни
Вот с этим мне намного удобнее работать (к примеру перевести всё это в двоичный вид и уже совершать различные операции.)

Кстати говоря, некоторые функции st3, насколько я знаю, написаны на python.
Ну вы поняли, нужно открыть **любой** файл в двоичном, либо 16-ричном виде.

Comment: Это не utf-8, это байтовая строка в экранированном виде. Вывести байтовую строку в 16-ричном виде можно с помощью функции `binascii.hexlify`

Comment: А на вход binascii.hexlify, нужно дать open(filename, 'rb').read()?

Comment: покажите *минимальный* пример файла, ваша попытка его прочитать, что вы *точно* получаете и конкретный пример, что вы хотите вместо этого получить¶ Открывайте файл в `'rb'` режиме и смотрите [Байты - перевод из строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/496420/23044) Подробнее: [How to open and present raw binary data in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33145337/4279)

Comment: @andreymal: можно `.hex()` метод вызвать вместо `binascii.hexlify()` функции. Хотя удобней, конечно, с байтами напрямую работать, а не  с hexdump