# Проблемы с кириллицей в python

Tags: python, url, utf-8

Проблема очень простая - банально не могу получить содержимое страницы с кириллическими символами, для примера взять хотя бы русскую Wikipedia.
Используя urllib делал так, но постоянно натыкаюсь на Exception

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse import quote


def get_content(name):
    print( urlopen('http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + quote(name)).readall()
           .decode('utf-8'))

get_content('лес')
```

такого вида:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xb2' in position 14187: character maps to <undefined>
```

Читал похожие вопросы в других обсуждениях, но не зависимо оттого, что я делаю с quote - результат пока тот же.
Быть может, делаю что-то глупое, но пока просто-напросто достать страницу из вики не выходит

Comment: На чем вы запускаете скрипт? Не из консоли Windows, случайно? Что говорит, например `sys.stdout.encoding`? Просто с `utf-8` всё должно работать.

Comment: Ошибка говорит, что у вас проблема с печатью текста (в консоле). См. [вот небольшой ликбез по выводу  Юникода в консоль на Питоне (проблема там другая, но решение одинаковое)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/414060/23044)

Comment: В сторону: не стоит utf-8 жёстко прописывать—html страничка может другую кодировку использовать. See [A good way to get the charset/encoding of an HTTP response in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14592762/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Просто нужно добавить

```
# coding=utf-8
from urllib import urlopen, quote


def get_content(name):
    return urlopen('http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + quote(name)).read()

print get_content('лес')
```

Comment: Нет, в комментариях ранее отметили - все дело в консольном выводе, а не кодировке. Использую PyCharm - их консоль (терминал) отличается не только от консоли самой Windows, но и вообще странно устроена.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно так поможет:

```
# ! /usr/bin/env python
# _*_ coding: utf-8 _*_

    print( urlopen(u'http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + quote(name)).readall()
       .decode('utf-8'))
```