# Python проблемы с кодировкой cp1251 в модуле lxml

Tags: python, xml, unicode, xmlparser, lxml

Проблема заключается в том, что при попытке распарсить xml-документ получаю ошибку:

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding!
```

Код:

```py
#-*- coding cp1251 -*-
import sys
from lxml import etree
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("cp1251")

inputFile = a.ED

tree = etree.parse(inputFile)
nodes = tree.xpath('/')
print nodes.decode('cp1251')
```

Windows 7, python 2.7, lxml 2.3

В документе:

```xml
<ED101 sysCode ="04">
<dsig:SigValue xmlns:dsig="urn">AAAA</dsig:SigValue>
<Name>Сергей Николаевич</Name>
</ED101>
```

Comment: Укажите кодировку xml-документа или перекодируйте его содержимое в utf-8.

Comment: не относится напрямую к вопросу, но стоит упомянуть: 1- `#-*- coding cp1251 -*-` строчка не имеет никакого эффекта в вашем Питон коде, т.к. в нём нет не-ascii символов. 2- не используйте `reload(sys); sys.setdefaultencoding("cp1251")` -- это просто способ испортить данные (без явных ошибок, которые бы на проблему указали) или [получить кракозябы на выходе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229015/23044). 3- `.decode('cp1251')` выглядит ошибочно. lxml должен и так возвращать `unicode` тип для не-ascii содержимого. Достаточно [печатать `unicode` напрямую.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/414060/23044)

Comment: Необходимо либо двоеточие либо знак равно после `coding` добавить, чтобы как декларация кодировки строчка воспринималась. Пример: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` (без двоеточия `SyntaxError` возникнет, если не-ascii символ исходном коде появится (в строковых константах, в комментариях).

Comment: @jfs Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky мои комментарии  не имеют отношения к проблеме с xml. Чтобы исправить XMLSyntaxError, нужно следовать рекомендации Sergey Gornostaev.

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev - Спасибо большое!

Comment: Всем большое спасибо за Коментарии сейчас буду пробовать.