# Прочитать кириллицу с rtf-файла Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, rtf

Столкнулся с проблемой на python3 - прочитать из файла текст на кириллице (rtf, txt  фаил). Выводит в терминал непонятные значения типа u/2424 и тд. Перепробовал все, не могу понять как перекодировать его чтобы выводил нормально. И как прочитать из файла одно слово? Спасибо за ответ!
Так же открывал таким методом. Вывод не меняется!

```
open('...', 'r', encoding='utf-8')

file = open('some_text.rtf', 'r')
print(file.readlines())
```

Вот такой вывод кирилицы:

```
['\xd0\x92\xd0\xb0\xd1\x88 \xd1\x88\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb2\xd1\x80 \xd0\xb3\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2!\n', '\xd0\xa1 \xd0\xb4\xd1\x80\xd1\x83\xd0\xb3\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb9
```

Comment: Покажите свой код и напишите, что он выводит фактически.

Comment: См. [Справка: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: В `open` есть параметр `encoding`, если его не указывать, кодировка берется системная. Укажите в нем кодировку файла. Например: `open('...', 'r', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: делал не помогает, вывод не меняеться

также писал в начале файла #encoding utf-8  тоже не помогло

Comment: @ВадимВова, добавьте в вопрос, с какой кодировкой открываете, и что выводится. Иначе это будет гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Кстати, RTF - это не plain-text формат. Почитайте, например здесь: [Хабрахабр: Текст любой ценой: RTF](https://habrahabr.ru/post/70119/)

Comment: Выводит набор цифры типа  u/2424
Та же ситуация и с .txt Возможно на маке другая кодировка?

Comment: @ВадимВова, еще раз. Выше вы пишете, что пробовали открывать с encoding. С какой кодировкой пробуете открывать? По поводу вывода - скопируйте и вставьте буквально то что выводит программа. Также посмотрите что на самом деле находится в файле (откройте файл с помощью блокнота, например).

Comment: То что вы привели в качестве вывода не соответствует по виду тому, что вы писали раньше. Видимо раньше вы открывали rtf, а теперь показываете вывод при открытии файла txt. Для открытия файла txt вам в данном случае скорее всего нужно указать кодировку cp1251.

Comment: @insolor спасибо, что опечатку поправили. Вывод показывает, что OP использует Питон 2, а не 3. То есть текстовый файл читается как байты (в UTF-8 кодировке в данном случае) и есть вероятность что [кракозябы при печати появятся в не UTF-8 окружении](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229015).

Comment: @jfs, может и так. Я сейчас попробовал записать эти данные в файл, потом прочитать с кодировкой utf-8 в Python3 - получилось `['Ваш шедевр готов!\n', 'С другой']`. Если бы в вопросе была описана внятная последовательность действий, и не два вопроса в одном, то можно было бы что-то посоветовать. А так можно только гадать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RTF - не plain-text файл и просто так из него ничего прочитать не выйдет. В нем дополнительно хранятся таблицы шрифтов, цветов, стилей и еще неведомо чего. Более того, судя по всему текст там хранится не в виде байтов u/1234, а в виде строк 'u/1234' (!) (или для другой подходящей кодировки, например, win-1251 - в этом случае кирилица представлена строками типа \'b2, \'a4). Благо, есть парочка старых библиотек. Вот пример для [pyth](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyth/) (для простого файла с одной строкой сработало):

```
from pyth.plugins.rtf15.reader import Rtf15Reader

doc = Rtf15Reader.read(open("doc.rtf", "r"))

for paragraph in doc.content:
    for word in paragraph.content:
        print(word.__dict__["content"])  # Вывод в виде unicode строки
```

С документацией плоховато и неизвестно как именно библиотека справляется с таблицами, изображениями.

Comment: Также открывать и текстовый файл (txt) есть ли разница при работе на маке или винде( имею ввиду, кодировку)

Comment: работает ли эта библиотека на Питоне 3?

Comment: @ВадимВова, если в open указывать правильную кодировку открываемого файла txt, то будет правильно открывать файлы и на маке, и на винде, и на линуксе.

Comment: @ВадимВова, если есть вопросы по txt - создвайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Похоже `pyth` работает только на Питоне 2 и не понимает `\ucN` команду и суррогатные пары (нужны для не BMP символов)

Answer (score 1):

Если на машине уже стоит LibreOffice, то можно на него опереться, чтобы поддерживать даже астральные символы такие как смайлики, флаги итд. `pyth` и большинство других rtf-библиотек могут потерять символы из rtf-документа с символами, требующих [utf-16 суррогатных пар](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), пример `test.rtf`:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1251\uc0 test [\'ff] [\u9786] [\u-10187\u-9138]
 [\u-10180\u-8710\u-10180\u-8712].}
```

Команда `$ rtf2txt test.rtf` сохраняет текст в `test.txt` и печатает его:

```
test [я] [☺] [] [].
```

где `rtf2txt`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Convert rtf-file(s) to plain text using LibreOffice.

  Usage: rtf2txt <rtf-file>...
"""
from getpass import getuser
from pathlib import Path
from subprocess import DEVNULL, check_call
from sys import argv
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory

filenames = argv[1:]
with TemporaryDirectory('LibreOffice_Conversion_' + getuser()) as td:
    check_call([
        'soffice',
        '--headless',  # implied by convert-to
        # https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Filter_Options
        '--infilter="Rich Text Format (StarCalc)"',  # limit input formats
        # specify the encoding explicitly for the output
        '--convert-to', 'txt:Text (encoded):UTF8',
        # https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37531
        '-env:UserInstallation=' + Path(td).as_uri()
    ] + filenames, stdout=DEVNULL)

for path in map(Path, filenames):
    print(path.with_suffix('.txt').read_text('utf-8'))
```