# Генерация rtf файлов с помощью Python3

Tags: python-3.x, rtf

Здравствуйте. Есть шаблонный rtf файл. С помощью Python3 делаю замену. Польские буквы не отображает в требуемом виде. При этом вывод из интерпретатора корректен. Заранее спасибо за помощь.
Ссылка на файл http://dropmefiles.com/GV7Va

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
with open("test.rtf") as file_in:
    text = file_in.read()
TEL_TAG = r'łacińskim'
text = text.replace("TEL_TAG", TEL_TAG)
with open("generated.rtf", "w") as file_out:
    file_out.write(text)
print(TEL_TAG)
```

Comment: создайте минимальный пример входного rtf файла. Явно приведите желаемый результат и что ваш код вместо этого выводит. Вот посмотрите в ответе пример rtf c разными символами представлен: [Прочитать кириллицу с rtf-файла Python 3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/530158/23044). А так можно только гадать: то ли у вас исходный код не в той кодировке сохранён, то ли локальная кодировка, используемая open() отличается от кодировки, в которой не-ascii неэкранированные символы в rtf явно записаны (если rtf позволяет это -- если не позволяет, то следует закодировать `TEL_TAG`, используя `\'`, `\u-`.

Comment: Проблему решил таким способом. Польские значения и символы загонял в RTF файл в закодированном виде, то есть в таком, в котором файл сможет их корректно прочитать. Например в приведенном выше коде переменная TEL_TAG = r'\u322\'3faci\u324\'3fskim' выводила в документе правильно łacińskim. А как напрямую писать в файл польские слова, так и не разобрался. Спасибо, что откликнулись.

Comment: Интересовала универсальная возможность сохранять rtf файлы с возможностью прочитать корректно польские буквы и сохранить форматирование в документе. Тогда следует следующий вопрос: как сохранить rtf файл и в какой кодировке чтобы корректно выводились указанные значения и сохранялось форматирование.

Comment: Извините. Поправил.

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример rtf-файла, который показывает два способа как слово `'łacińskim'` можно записать:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg852\uc0
[\'88aci\'e4skim]
[łacińskim]
}
```

Первое слово записано, используя экранированные `\'xx` последовательности,  где `xx` — это байт, записанный в шестнадцатеричной системе, представляющий символ, закодированный  в cp852 кодировке.

Второе слово записано напрямую в cp852 кодировке. При сохранении rtf-файла, убедитесь, что cp852 кодировка используется. К примеру, на моей системе, если я скопирую этот текст и вставлю в текстовый файл, то он сохранится в utf-8 кодировке и чтобы получить нужный файл, необходимо выполнить команду дополнительно:

```
$ iconv --from utf-8 --to cp852 polish.rtf | sponge polish.rtf
```

При генерации файла с помощью Питона, достаточно явно указать кодировку:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pathlib import Path

text = Path('test.rtf').read_text(encoding='cp852')
text = text.replace('LATIN_PLACEHOLDER', 'łacińskim')
Path('generated.rtf').write_text(text, encoding='cp852')
```

Обратите внимание, Питон код закодирован в utf-8 (ничего не надо менять).