# Какие-то вопросики в восстановленном после удаления джава манифесте

Tags: java, android

Востанавил удаленный с диска  проект с помощью программы.Вроде папка весит 118 мб но открыв папку рот упал до колен ... все классы джава манифест все как то непонятно какието вопросики 
Вот пример манифеста ...

```
    p��K��3�w�a=.������j��d层�Q�����Pۺ�qZӇ:��y'�'�9�Pb
���WY��    ���]mh����-�4����a���ҭn
�?v�xʌd��^�^��Kit�i��)���m��=*Ԧ4t�,�*��;t:�B�l����;#�<oF�B��D����:U��5�+m�W,�Kȶ�T,��1�5u�eP��>̯��An{��,ɋ]K+*�RU*�T�w�\G�C.�]��/�G�j%��_*Vo�Ap�1�f��W���Uy˹�{8��g'udMJ�jc������Ƞ�� J�kQ�<�ʌ��\��m���e͹�x�Y���w�p�� �<���t#=�k�� ���� i����:�َ��sLC�����7����*|ڑ�-�W�u���"J��"e���#�Oݣ�w�
f��+#�Y�l,��r�gFL⡶��|��HS�?q�X�Ӻ�Ӳ1�Y�c!|�*����IԿ��w������h�7�EU`ӈ��=x��\9�ePa�kp)��
��̂��X]#EC2������#��'`=)�FU�DR�q�g�|�9�xn�ȗS�Aِ��aQݡէ�C�?܉
 FA� #�ɶ�"��j��)溔�b�)�"xݭ"RD��x*p�>�q#�E�4���<�{���7%��
�12HX@�G�qZ��s^L�7�����:#O�̻3y�`��7j�"2������~��5<��h��X�$R��ex�J��9U��EHѸd    �8�õeN<�ԗʦ.Yn�o�E�2t#�T7sH��&�;yh�cq?ʻ�Qv2�7l�-�� �p3H��Z�q��t9毖�­K�2ʱy�+;�?�� U���ZiY�� J�;hg����q�`8�9��ɓas����gzi�hN��kD0�dv�yFB��Un��v4jvc��� ���ݰp�����oaE�mPc��=i�F�F�(a���Z��.�kZ}�!�T��f8c�����b�VO0n3.��Z�s�J�3E��.s���F�xa��
d�Z�p手��+1ݒ��y���������"g�F�#V#3����Kݕ�R��kf$��7a=F8�W���J,� b,�~��m�v8�Tw.�FReBA
0W8�S(�Lv�[j��=:�sݛTk�D�6�����W�#UbB����3�W,9�'�fԓj���W�4ͻ#��c#��S�C<�h�k�l$�ǧ4���G3����ҝ�t%+I�+�P�v��%�m�֕.#�Fу�0C�1�&���Z��M�Vy��$��y�v#K,�;��Y�w����UFN.�u�����@ż�7#樴���Q[�7��k�2�V&�>Tf��\�h�v�I���4m��yo�d�5n�9�$��Y�Q�>ɛ�.N>��X#*�Bp?ʦQ�<�J���
��_x_/���_j�O�K*G�b�t���u��*4��<(�Z36������~wP��pz�V
��~C�O��>��y�[�6��c5��#��j7�8Ժ>+�C��m�y�';EZ�C�dE.X~"������{Rrca���y'�Y���.�'i��������̞1�B_h��1_-��b�XH,�?覯���T�>L��c{�����<�|w�   ���"^p3U�����A+:$�$��ɿ���~�M�� �� �S _s�㪸�q� W,Y�끜{{w���[��;�UbO�Y�)�7sX�-"*�8���E(�Yt�� r�Ͻ&T%bġ6>&a>1�g�UG�G"�:�`�z#�J�$����8��EFثe�wr�ҩh��S�Z���\�9���0|�X����[|qG,��"^ �(ǌ��N��c�)O��oo�Z�uG��Y�D����0G@M,2L�3��W#;�Oz���Hy[4���R˿p��)��QZ�XL&$$3����G�k*��&vѕ�D��]�� d����/
j:��m����<�BЩ�4�r�q��A����0Gq
J�,�HN9����0,Q�m��r����}�Q�&���s�)r��v��Yx2�;x>��R��U��?Z�-4�:�'�@���xs_WO�����V��⻎٣�(VP�!�V����X�.OU����I������졶�,��ȫ2�b>�Wy,ckx�gX��$W�K/�S�1A�.��2���z�!�a©/��s����l��+��x��ͰJ�o�g.��L�5.d��g�2�{օ�y���˒X�ҿ���8����nt��Z�O�AdGR�Y�Pk��!k���r��+�[�Gk����0�E�����kU��(*��|�qZa���k���r�r�J�0�vh��g��f(�yg�ۈ������U�Vg��q�tQ\���e�N8�[��3.�PIW�~��]2w��6�#�.������?OҴlgX�Y�s�G$g��yl�<������PF�R��*�2z֔��&���z,^�����B��QN��q 's1����]��r���6pH�h�9����Vpb�po�n�W��w��t�oz�o�'�ѣd�&N$Dbs��:|��dp�߁�+�u9U�����̖+�9Op��"�a�wd�L���¼��Κ������(Y��}Oq�J/����h��fܼ��#T���p*�r[�HV7��ė��y�_���ab�nX� V7w�߻�6�ZIREB���j�Q-S���`0p� a��jz䐣A�ӐsG?4
c���V��!����Z6��Fd����}}k˝>vuQ���eF�%_�
0��hY  �@�Eqbi]3�S�vGY�@U�T�j�ֻ���Eu~X{�X�|�i��c�Ӫ��.|�Xs�zT�O�y������x8=��Z#�Qj)7�d*�b?=��1�ߥcʄ.23����vƭ��3�Z�n�'��';X����g��|�w�U>P3�y��9�%�u��娏��!w �(�>� N8'� �_Mxz�f�̩�,yoο ��|����iE������ͱ��#��]*�<�~�>n���<}f�C����nw֎^TS)��H��I��Ԓo,�2  �\��v�����̳p�:��Y�Q��jn�M�����+
�U�����Wd3j(@*����Xw��a�Iy����N���������i�v�۞��Z�Y��
*�Y�oOz�pt�����\������.3����d�?:��ݎB���P��Wg�c*�r�9ز)d'�潳�dlѾ7���Ue��q��6��w�l ʈ��v�g��e�%�'=q_�f,��0�tH�g�,���õr:�!Q�Ev<ޞ��a�s5r�t�Q�Z�N���*�����bu��<�� y� v���'}O�̣Κ>@��)��.s�+���V�� v6H�E���R�����<��x��gA��?8�S�{���ZrX��t���F �v��s�+�O�� wB)��f�c-��9� t�i��B�O�^�5&�G-��*0=�H���hZH����p ���m=j.��f��q�H$�c޲�Wl�yfE�v?���I���y�fQ�U ��M�h�c��>xG�#��6��q���e�y�ϟ�F�FSd2�}�aI���X�    n��� �׾��&������G��H��p�<V��+ٲX��+�s���2K��gn>c�j�O�V5.PfiP��s�Z��UI3�9��S%Ȯ]9]�bx�0Q� ��4�fT���YS��Υ=t�ٕ    (��܊�dF *������R6G� s�
zH$�^�N �%ٽc��V�z�cʵ&@�� n�j��8(O�1��޸����N�`-��G�������,�k����=(��&.��2��
Ny�J��7"�rzW=(�5�Wr�L�#g 7˺�2��?xs�Oz+4�����
�݆y@��~��UcNYK8�������Jwf8��N�L� &���8��Yw2"� b샕kݍ;�X�·-�L�y������*���)$75�1�X�E�e9'���O_ʨK)`69�#?J졆�x8��6����4�%�9���Z�h��K��1%A#=�ɼ�\��:��*�yJ��� ��}�j����^������z�d�.8g8� `��O�}
sK]N:-;��.�w,9c�V�0�>�N2Ú������5"��1\���SW�vy��3�O�S����ў��,M����M�^ ����<�8gp�ħ��,\o�=�T屹f�lV� �c�r+n�p�2��s�+�qK�=�3�,:�L�������㏉Q�p>�=�]xH(&o9t4-���X�%�6��隕W
���z�����W�mnd"@ʪ�ʌ��/F�;U�Q�����=닕��ƚqE�4e�k�nz����P��>���OR��I�wZ�F�t��#��=w��8 �c��e(�Di֣�m�!dQ�q����2�$>��
��+�#R����=�XUIS&P�t+�
��|�*] %s"1u����Y����co�� WMD��3��H�M��Y<Ͻ�� c����V��
ޞX�՗��v1dF�-�����i|�\�ݷC�[Е�<l\��+��2��^1�k��y�/��;�|�n9�_KB^�#���;�3.��~��d�Ċ]|�N S��ק*����Xά��)FX�nH�k1T�BNJ�d��Ʋ����^$O����z��b�F�^��4��L�t�7�1e�w�NN�z��Jy��`A�8�\.V�H�����ay/�L�R�>�]��Id!�Nk%UBJ�C��"�ʚ�Cu\�hW:!�thrH5Ǐƴ���Q�ǿ�|�,?u����J<�uߑ� �^E<ɩ\�>t^�FHU�F�� }kn(bi6G�B��O�㰭�f*��4��nٿm�ң.8���+���DA0e��ǌ�� *婈���yn��ܟ�����E�0���M:^�r�YVB@�w��k
��]��W>e��0$:�bQ�q�Z��E�L��#�������;#ONS��Xm���b�+0�8����|����,0E{\Ũr�r�±�?�k��o��uu�b����u�n*�M)Y�B\�C��i:]����Zچi���ך���U�����Ѵ⸷������&��k쩹3�������vX�e*���ǭ3^�/L��|N��B§����ϔ������i�jRG4�G�� r:ҽ>�I���:{k���Z��J���*>g�u%h��/\��
�J-�m��m0�kž,�g���3\��e�*�����
```

Неужели нет выхода ?что посоветуете

Comment: Попробуй поменять кодировку.

Comment: как это можно реализоать?

Comment: Ну вот то, что в вопросе - в принципе похоже на отображение utf-8 открытой в какой-то экзотической кодировке. Про "все файлы классов манифесты" я не совсем понял

Comment: "Все люди делятся на тех кто не использует Git и тех кто **уже** использует Git"(c)

Comment: Быда вин 7 сделал винд8 в итоге в C диске удалились  проекты. Востановил через программу . открыл и место классов Активити  идут такие записи .што за код ептчто делать

Comment: Юрий возможно востановление ??? Мнн очень важен этот проект ...

Comment: @elik, единственное что мне в голову прихоит - кодировку проверить

Comment: @elik, ну или сегодня был вопрос про восстанвление кода из apk файл если он где-то есть

Comment: [блок-схема  для кракозябр](https://web.archive.org/web/20130517202358/http://gamejam.ru/files/codepages.png). Можно ещё рассмотреть вариант, что вы архив или картинку как текст пытаетесь интерпретировать. [Пример кода на Питоне как кракозябры декодировать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229015/23044)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб похоже это не кодировка. Попробовал разные декодировщики, которые умеют расшифровывать запутанные кодировки, в том числе множественные, но результат так и остался нечитаем.

Comment: Да я тоже попробовал)в конце декоспилировал проект ) ну слав богу по большей части код невредим   читаем но выводы сделать можно)