# Перевод ascii кода в utf-8 и наоборот, при выводе в файл

Tags: python, python-2.x, telegram-bot, python-2.7

**Код**

```
fileopen = open('log.txt', mode="wa")
fileopen.write(message.chat.username + ' ' + message.text + '\n')
```

Пишу бота для Telegram на **python 2.7**. message - это объект, который может выдавать символы в utf-8 **на русском** в том числе *message.text.username* и *message.text*.
Как сделать так, чтобы интерпретатор правильно всё вывел в файл и перенёс там где у меня **'\n'** на следующую строку в файле

**Ошибка**

```
fileopen.write(message.chat.username + ' ' + message.text + '\n')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position
8-12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Похоже у вас unicode и байты вперемежку идут. Этого не следует делать. [Используйте Unicode для текста](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/414060/23044). Проверьте типы переменных (`type()`). Используйте `io.open()`, явно указав кодировку (encoding), чтобы Unicode в файл писать.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую изменить, если ничего не выйдет, попрошу помощи

Comment: @jfs у меня почему-то при открытии файла выходит проблема **TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function**
Я добавил туда encoding='utf-8', а mode изменил с 'wa' до 'a', ибо на сколько я понимаю, это одно и тоже

Comment: open != io.open

Comment: @jfs Я просто бесконечно благодарен. Это было действительно очень важно, и ни на одном форуме я не нашёл, спасибо огромное ещё раз

Comment: [Ссылка выше](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/414060/23044) в моём комментарии полный пример кода с io.open содержит.