# регулярное выражение отрабатывает онлайн но не работает в интерпретаторе питон

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-2.7

Почему одно и то же регулярное выражение нормально отрабатывает на сайтах типа [pythex.org](http://pythex.org) но все время возвращает пустой список в ходе выполнения программы?

Строка которую пытаюсь парсить:

```
info = u'\nOutage start time:\r\n        3/23/2017 5:11:12 AM\n\nEstimated restoration time:\n\n\n\n\n\nEstimated customers impacted:\r\n1\n\nReason:\r\n        An object has made contact with power lines in your area. SRP crews are working to restore power as quickly as possible.\n\nImpacted area:\r\nS SCHNEPF RD to N QUAIL RUN LN and E JUDD RD to W MAGMA RD\n\n'
```

Регулярное выражение:     `(?<=start time:)(.*?)(?=Estimated)`

Результат на сайте:     `3/23/2017 5:11:12 AM`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат в интерпретаторе (Python 2.7):

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=start time:)(.*?)(?=Estimated)', info, re.UNICODE)
[]
>>> re.findall(ur'(?<=start time:)(.*?)(?=Estimated)', info, re.UNICODE)
[]
```

Comment: [Вроде работает вот так](https://ideone.com/eGD762). А у вас?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не хватает [`re.DOTALL` флага](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL), так как ввод многострочный.

```
>>> re.findall(ur'(?<=start time:)(.*?)(?=Estimated)', info, re.UNICODE|re.DOTALL)
[u'\r\n        3/23/2017 5:11:12 AM\n\n']
```

Альтернативно, можно явно пробел указать в regex (если нас интересуют только даты, в которых нет перевода строки внутри):

```
>>> re.findall(ur'(?<=start time:)\s*(.*?)\s*(?=Estimated)', info, re.UNICODE)
[u'3/23/2017 5:11:12 AM']
```

Comment: `re.DOTALL` тут не нужен, так как нужная информация находится на 1 строке.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew **неверно**. Посмотрите на результат в первом примере: явно видно что он с `"\r\n"` начинается. В Питоне (и многих других языках) `"\n"` это символ новой строки. То есть "нужная информация" (дата) находится как минимум на второй строчке.

Comment: То, что информация на второй строчке, это не обсуждается.  `re.DOTALL` изменяет поведение точки, а не то, на каких строчках находится совпадение. Т.к. данное отличие заявлено как основная причина проблемы, этот ответ неправилен. Кроме того, использование блоков просмотра вперед и назад в данном случае излишне, т.к. `re.findall` возвращает содержимое звхватывающих групп, если они определены в выражении (в данном случае, они есть).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew прочтите хотя бы заголовок вопроса: `re.DOTALL` может объяснить *почему* одно и то же регулярное выражение работает в одном случае и не работает в другом. А так много вариантов может быть *как* сделать рабочее regex (пара вариантов приведена в ответе).

Answer (score 1):

Если вы работаете со строками Юникода, необходимо все строки преобразовывать в необходимый вид (либо объявляя строковый литералы с помощью префикса `u`, либо используя `.decode` / `.encode`).

[Рабочий код](https://ideone.com/ji7EmL) с использованием вашей строки:

```
import re
info = u'\nOutage start time:\r\n        3/23/2017 5:11:12 AM\n\nEstimated restoration time:\n\n\n\n\n\nEstimated customers impacted:\r\n1\n\nReason:\r\n        An object has made contact with power lines in your area. SRP crews are working to restore power as quickly as possible.\n\nImpacted area:\r\nS SCHNEPF RD to N QUAIL RUN LN and E JUDD RD to W MAGMA RD\n\n'
print([x.encode('utf8') for x in re.findall(ur'start time:\s*(.*?)\s*Estimated', info)])
# => ['3/23/2017 5:11:12 AM']
```

Comment: так у меня строка с префиксом **u**, этого недостаточно?

Comment: Нет, недостаточно. Кстати, не нужен модификатор `re.UNICODE`, так как в вашей регулярке нет предопределенных символьных классов `\w`, `\d` или даже границы слова `\b` (с помощью `re.UNICODE` эти операторы начинают распознавать соответствующие символы Юникода).

Comment: Ваш вариант работает, спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, если мой ответ помог вам решить проблему, отметьте ответ как решение (см. [*Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?*](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста. я вижу Вы изменили регулярку - т.е начальный вариант все таки был неправильным?

Comment: Нет, регулярку я не изменил. Просто исправил объявление входного литерала.

Comment: Используйте Unicode для работы с текстом. Печатайте Unicode напрямую. НЕ следует в байты текст превращать, используя жёстко прописанную кодировку (почему вы utf-8 выбрали? А если у человек на Винде в cmd запустить? Так [кракозябры получаются](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229015/23044)

Comment: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`  в вышеприведенном коде необязателен, он и не главное. Если ТС не вводит строки от руки, пример с `encode/decode` очень даже кстати.