# Русские символы в регулярных выражениях python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-2.7

```
if "!anon" in message:
  ss = re.compile(ur"^!anon")
else:
  ss = re.compile(ur"^!анон")
print(message)
message = ss.sub(u"", message).encode("utf-8").strip()
```

Почему, если написать `!anon` - его удаляет, а `!анон` - нет?

Comment: Связанный вопрос [How to remove the left part of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/599953/4279)

Answer (score 3):

Для работы с текстом используйте Unicode в Питоне.

Ваш Python 2 код работает, если `isinstance(message, unicode)`. [Пример](https://repl.it/Jpd2/1):

```
print re.sub(u'б', '', 'абба') #XXX DOESN'T WORK
# -> абба
print re.sub(u'б', '', u'абба')
# -> аа
```

`'б'` в `'абба'` константе в Питоне 2 создаёт последовательность байт по умолчанию (объект типа `bytes`), аналог `b'\xd0\xb1'` в Питоне 3 (предполагая Питон 2 исходный код объявлен с utf-8 кодировкой, иначе `б` другой последовательностью байтов может быть представлена). Обратите внимание, вы даже не можете `b'б'` записать в Питоне 3 (`SyntaxError`).

Не смешивайте байты и unicode. Питон 3 выбросил бы TypeError, если бы вы попытались использовать unicode  регулярное выражение с `isinstance(message, bytes)`. Питон 2 здесь за кадром выполняет аналог [`u'б'.encode('latin-1')`, что ведёт к ошибке](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29317102/4279).

В общем случае, может потребоваться `re.UNICODE` флаг, чтобы к примеру `\w+` регулярное выражение распознавало Юникодные буквы и цифры.

Уберите `.encode('utf-8')` — этот путь ведёт к [кракозябрам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229015/23044). Используйте байты только на границе с интерфейсами, которые их явно требуют. Внутри программы передавайте текст в виде Unicode.