# Почему нужно задавать параметр encoding в open(file, encoding='utf-8')?

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка

`print(sys.getdefaultencoding())` показывает, что в системе по умолчанию стоит кодировка `utf-8`

Мне нужно считать файл (в моем случае `txt`, но наверно это не важно) в кодировке `utf-8` содержащий кириллицу.
Но если не задавать параметр `encoding`, то автоматически происходит перевод в `ASCI` и кириллица превращается в абракадабру.

Мне просто нужно с этим считаться и задавать параметр `encoding`? Или все-таки можно это обойти?

Comment: Если еще кто подскажет, как лучше задать вопрос, то буду признателен)

Comment: В чем проблема указать encoding при открытии, если вы точно знаете, что файл записан в utf-8?

Comment: @insolor Наверно проблемы никакой, до тех пор пока я это точно знаю. Просто стало интересно, почему нужно все равно явно указывать, хотя по умолчанию аргумент encoding=None, соответственно почему бы не брать кодировку, которая по умолчанию в системе?

Comment: Без понятия. Но даже если бы бралась системная кодировку по-умолчанию, то не факт что она совпадет с кодировкой файла. Поэтому либо нужно знать кодировку файла, либо определять ее как в вопросе по ссылке в вашем ответе, и указывать ее при открытии.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо просто нужно принять это как данность. 
И вопрос мой получается риторический.

Нашел [вопрос 2-х летней давности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/700664/341734)

Вряд-ли что-то изменилось, там приведено два варианта обхода этой "задачи".