# Названия с русскими буквами файлов загруженных на сайт Java EE отображаются иероглифами

Tags: ubuntu, файлы, файловая-система, кодировка

Подскажите пожалуйста. Как пофиксить проблему с русскими символами в файлах?
загружаю файлы на сайт Java EE. Название русскими символами и отображаются они в виде иероглифов. Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: что у вас `locale` выводит. Откуда файлы взялись. `touch абв` создаёт `абв` файл? Покажите как у вас [кракозябры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229015/23044) выглядят.

Comment: У меня  вопрос: а зачем вообще есть в русские символы в названиях файлов, которые ты загружаешь на сайт?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-ru
```

Затем:

```
sudo nano -w /etc/default/locale
```

В нём делаем

```
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
```

Затем

```
sudo locale-gen ru_RU.UTF-8
sudo update-locale
```

Comment: 1. пакет language-pack-ru (точнее, language-pack-ru-base) в данном случае абсолютно не нужен. 2. по поводу того, что написано после слова «затем»: а что, в убунту, как обычно, поломали дебиановскую **интерактивную** конфигурацию пакета locales? (`dpkg-reconfigure locales`)

Comment: Там универсального рецепта не существует. Я же не знаю, какая из Ubuntu у него стоит. Часто хостеры на VPS ставят свои неведомые патчи, которые ломают в том числе локали.