# Проблема с оператором raw_print()

Tags: python, python-2.x

Доброго времени суток, столкнулся с проблемой в python 2.7
 в заголовке указанно  # -x- coding: utf-8 -x-(i'm sorry for x)
в теле программы есть строка с raw_input(u'текст на русском').
Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы в скобках оператора raw_input появился русский текст?
Тему гуглил, не помогло. Все примеры кривые и относятся к python 3.0 or higher.

Comment: Что значит "чтобы в скобках оператора raw_print появился русский текст"?

Comment: нет такой встроенной функции `raw_print()`. Вы вероятно о `raw_input()` говорите. На Windows, win-unicode-console пакет можно использовать, чтобы обойти https://bugs.python.org/issue7768 Related: [Unicode input with raw_input() in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32725922/4279)

Comment: Да, я прошу прощения, за ошибку. r a w _input(и"Сколько тебе лет? ")

Comment: import codecs, sys / outf=codecs.getwriter('cp866')(sys.stdout, errors='replace') / sys.stdout=outf слеш переход строки, такой код нашел в справочной литературе, но он не работает. На экране вместо русского текста вопросы и иероглифы.

Comment: пакет поставили?

Comment: при попытке выполнить файл получаю такое сообщение: raceback (most recent call last):
  File "2.py", line 4, in <module>
    uotf=codecs.getwriter('cp866')(sys.stduot, errors='replace')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'stduot'

Comment: к сожалению я работаю на linux mint

Comment: @ИльяЛозаненко на linux mint, чтобы не заморачиваться на Питоне 2, просто `u` уберите: `raw_input('текст на русском')` так как интерфейс с байтами работает. Внутри программы unicode используйте для текста, превращая в байты только по необходимости при общении с внешним миром. Или просто на Питон 3.

Comment: предыдущий вариант предполагает, что окружение ожидает текст в utf-8 кодировке (что крайне вероятно для linux mint). Но если это не так (к примеру, на Windows запустите), то [можете кракозябры получить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229015/23044). Решение из принятого ответа громоздкое, но будет работать и на русской Винде (win-unicode-console позволил бы русский текст вне зависимости chcp значения, то есть не только на русской Windows).

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, учту в работе)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверил, нормально работает как в консоли Windows с кодировкой CP866, так и в консоли Debian с кодировкой UTF-8.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys

x = raw_input(u'текст на русском\n'.encode(sys.stdout.encoding))
print x
```

Comment: спасибо, огромное, у меня данный код записан немного в другой последовательности!!! Я как в справочнике взял пример, так его и вставил.

Comment: Да, действительно, все работает. Еще раз, спасибо!