# При запуске subprocess команды с кириллицей происходит ошибка: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode

Tags: python, windows, python-2.x, кириллица, subprocess

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import argparse
import ctypes
import subprocess
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='test')
parser.add_argument('-f', help = 'folder')
args = parser.parse_args()
path = args.f
if ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin() != 0:
    print 'You  admin\n'
    output = subprocess.check_output(['takeown', '/F', path, '/R', '/A'])
    print output
    output2 = subprocess.check_output(['icacls', path, '/grant:r', 'Администраторы:F'])
    print output2
else:
    print 'You not admin'
    exit(0)
```

[image: Ошибка]
Как отобразить? "Администраторы"

Comment: про отобразить: [Проблемы с кодировкой Python 2.7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229015/23044)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Почему UnicodeEncodeError при вызове subprocess.check_output()

Traceback показывает, что `subproces.check_output()` вызывает `subprocess.Popen`, которая на Windows вызывает [`_subprocess.CreateProcess` на Питоне 2](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/19f6bd06af3c7fc0db5f96878aaa68f5589ff13e/Lib/subprocess.py#L635-L644).

Благодаря `from __future__ import unicode_literals` директиве: `'abc'` у вас имеет unicode тип (Python 2).

[`sp_CreateProcess` преобразует unicode аргумент в байты (`char*`), используя `'z'` формат](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/19f6bd06af3c7fc0db5f96878aaa68f5589ff13e/PC/_subprocess.c#L446), который использует кодировку по умолчанию (`sys.getdefaultencoding() == 'ascii'` на Питоне 2). См. [Parsing arguments and building values](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/arg.html).

Так как используется CreateProcessA() WinAPI (не Unicode) на Windows в Питоне 2, то перед передачей в subprocess, руками попробуйте закодировать не-ascii аргументы, используя ANSI codepage:

```
args = [u'icacls', path, u'/grant:r', u'Администраторы:F']
args = [arg.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding()) for arg in args]
subprocess.check_call(args)
```

#### Почему кракозябры в traceback

На Питоне 2, `'abc'` строковая константа (string literal) это последовательность байт, представляющая символы, записанные в исходном коде, в кодировке, указанной наверху файла (`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` -- PEP 263 encoding declaration). `from __future__ import unicode_literals` директива превращает `'abc'` (байты) в `u'abc'` (unicode).

Кракозябры могут появиться, когда текст, закодированный в одной кодировке, показывается используя другую (несовместимую) кодировку:

```
>>> print(u'Администраторы:F'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp866'))
╨Р╨┤╨╝╨╕╨╜╨╕╤Б╤В╤А╨░╤В╨╛╤А╤Л:F
```

Исходный код (utf-8) как байты напрямую без перекодировки выводится в консоль (cp866 здесь), поэтому вы видите кракозябры -- это можно  считать багом в Питоне 2.