# Как вытащить значение msg из data?

Tags: python, json

Есть код на питоне

```
data = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen("http://...").read())
```

С сайта скачивается текст:

```
{"msg":"Text"}
```

И я никак не могу вытащить значение msg из data. Print data возвращает ошибку. Что я делаю не так и как мне получить свои данные?

Comment: @mikelsv, вы уверены, что `urllib2...read()` возвращает именно то, что нужно?

Comment: print json.dumps(urllib2.urlopen... выводит "{'msg':'Text'}"

Comment: @mikelsv, одиночные апострофы - это невалидный json. Если есть доступ к серверу - надо поменять сериализацию, если нет - менять апострофы на кавычки и надеяться на лучшее.

Comment: Всем валидный, питону нет. Ок, replace("'", "\"").

Comment: @mikelsv, по спеке невалидный.

Comment: `print json.dumps(urllib2.urlopen..` выглядит неправильно. Что происходит, если попробовать: `print(urllib2.urlopen..`? Что печатает: `print repr(data['msg'])`?

Answer (score 1):

В [доках](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) написано, что следуют [RFC 4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627.html). В стандарте не нашел упоминание про одинарные кавычки, "все", наверное, не полностью следуют стандарту )

К тому же:

```
a = "{'msg':'Text'}"
json.loads(a) # ValueError: Expecting property name
```

но при этом:

```
a = u"{'msg':'Text'}"
json.loads(a) # ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes
```

Т.е. если бы привели к UTF-8, то ошибка была бы информативнее )

Тем более, что по тому же стандарту:

> > "A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters".

Comment: Ой... я кавычки перепутал ) Но ошибки - верны.

Comment: Несоответствие данных приведённым ошибкам вводит в заблуждение. `{"msg":"Text"}` - это правильный json текст. OP говорит, что ошибка возникает на этапе `print data` *после* успешного json распознавания.

Comment: @jfs, я же в комментарии поправился - кавычки перепутал. Т.е. надо не '{"msg":"Text"}', а "{'msg':'Text'}". Чтобы не смущало, сейчас поправлю. Это во-первых.

А во-вторых - вы комментарий ТС выше посмотрите - у него невалидный JSON. Вы же не знаете, как он его получает, он, может, в блок try парсинг вставил. Вот и при парсинге ошибки нет.

Либо "Print data" у него имеется ввиду: print json.loads

Comment: Я читал первый комментарий и не мог понять, почему ответ не был отредактирован. Существует какой-то лимит на редактирование своего ответа?

Comment: @jfs, вроде как 10 редактирований автором делает ответ "вики-ответом", раньше, по крайней мере, так было. Я как-то не претендую на "вики", поэтому стараюсь лишний раз не редактировать )

А вообще - лень было )) Комментарий быстрее написать было.

Answer (score 0):

Если ошибка возникает только во время вывода на печать, то проблема может быть в печати Юникодных строк в консоли. `repr()` может вернуть ascii представление для строки, чтобы помочь отладить проблему:

```
import json
from contextlib import closing
from urllib2 import urlopen
url = "http://..."
with closing(urlopen(url)) as r:
    data = json.load(r)
print repr(data['msg'])
print data['msg']
```

Если ошибка возникает только на втором `print`, то можно установить переменную окружения `PYTHONIOENCODING` в кодировку, которая понимает все символы в `data['msg']`, например, `utf-8` и перенаправить вывод в файл, если кодировка в консоли не utf-8. [Как из Python вывести на Windows-консоль строку в Юникоде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/141035/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7-python-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-windows-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5) На Unix это проще, достаточно использовать utf-8 локаль, например, C.UTF-8 или ru_RU.utf8.