# urllib Python 3.4 проблема с кодировкой

Tags: python, python-3.x

версия Питона 3.4

я установил на ubuntu локальный сервер и все это работает через браузер.
есть такой код:

```
#python 3.4
import urllib.request

url = 'http://ya.ru'
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
respData = resp.read()
print(respData)
```

вся информация взятая из указанного сайта, на выходе(на браузере) отображаетя вот в таком формате:

```
b'
картикни(jpg, png, ...)
ссылки
кнопки и поля для заполнения
только вот вместо кирилицы показыет такую крякозябру \xd0\x9a\xd1\x83\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c
'
```

все содержимое сайта как вы видите в ковычках а перед ковычками буква b (b' ')
и текста очень много.

Моя цель. Получить только текст из указанного сайта. но вместо текста получаю крякозябры (\xd0\x9a\xd1\x83\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c)

Вопрос: как это исравить? учитывая что содержимое сайтов на входе будут на русском и на английских языках.

Answer (score 3):

Нужно испосльзовать метод [**`.decode()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=decode#bytes.decode) потому что `respData` является  байт строка.

```
import urllib.request

url = 'http://example.com'
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
respData = resp.read()
print(respData.decode())
```

Примера:

```
>>> b"\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \xd0\x9a\xd1\x83\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c \r\n\t\t\t\t\t".decode()
'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t Купить \r\n\t\t\t\t\t'
```

Я думаю, что вы бы хотели удалить пробелы тогда:

```
>>> b"\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \xd0\x9a\xd1\x83\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c \r\n\t\t\t\t\t".decode().strip()
'Купить'
```

Answer (score 3):

`resp.read()` возвращает двоичные данные (`bytes`), которые могут быть представлены в виде текста, используя `b'..'` константы (`repr()`). Чтобы получить текст (Unicode) необходимо знать соответствующую кодировку:

```
unicode_text = bytestring.decode(character_encoding)
bytestring = unicode_text.encode(character_encoding)
```

Не ясно, зачем выводить в консоль html-код веб-страницы, но если хочется:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import io
import urllib.request
import shutil
import sys

url = 'http://ya.ru'
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as r, \
    io.TextIOWrapper(r, encoding=r.headers.get_content_charset('utf-8')) as file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(file, sys.stdout)
```

Подробнее о том как узнать кодировку текста, возвращаемого http-сервером, см.: [A good way to get the charset/encoding of an HTTP response in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14592762/4279).

---

Если возникают проблемы с печатью Юникода на Винде, то установи `win-unicode-console` пакет, см.: [Как из Python вывести на Windows-консоль строку в Юникоде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/359348/23044) На других системах достаточно [локаль настроить](https://askubuntu.com/q/33025/3712) (см. `LANG`, `LC_ALL`, `LC_CTYPE` переменные окружения) например:

```
$ LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 python3 your-script.py
```

Comment: Спасибо, много для себя полезного узнал  в тех ссылках которые отправили, но сам код конкретно не решает проблему.

Comment: @smajn: в чём конкретно ошибка: "если запустить код (из ответа как есть), то он показывает ... вместо ожидаемых ...") (заполните многоточие, пожалуйста).

Comment: [screenshot](http://2.firepic.org/2/images/2015-09/20/wuc9itx1o0at.png) вот, ругается. вместо того чтобы показать содержимое страницы в читаемом виде.

Comment: @smajn: то что у Вас `sys.stdout` имеет `ascii` кодировку, указывает на сломанное окружение. На Ubuntu всё проще чем на 
Windows. Просто локаль настройте. Я обновил ответ.

Comment: все равно ругается(( . я написал в терминале: "LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 python3 your-script.py". а он выдает такую ошибку. can't open file 'your-script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @smajn: это уже у Вас **третья** проблема (первая: как получить текст из байтов, вторая: как Юникодный текст напечатать). Третья: `your-script.py` -- это просто пример (буквальный перевод с английского: `ваша-программа.py`) -- используйте настоящее имя файла, куда Вы сохранили код из ответа.