# lxml вместо кириллицы выводит (байты?) \xd0 например

Tags: python, utf-8, lxml

```
import requests
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO, BytesIO

def getPage(url):
    return requests.get(url)


def main():
    parser = etree.HTMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
    resp_obj = getPage("https://freelance.ru/projects/?spec=4&page=1")
    page = resp_obj.content.decode(resp_obj.encoding).encode('utf-8').decode("utf-8")
    tree = etree.parse(StringIO(page), parser)
    root = tree.getroot()
    div_projects = root.xpath("//div[@class='projects']")[0]
    projects = div_projects.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "public")]')
    for project in projects:
        print(etree.tostring(project,encoding='UTF-8',pretty_print=True, method="html"))

main()
input()
```

А на выводе получаю
"\xd0 \xb0" и т.д. вместо кириллицы

Может кто подскажет, как нормально вывести?

Comment: http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#tounicode вместо string нужно использовать tounicode, пример кода если найду напишу. use tostring(el, encoding='unicode') instead.

Comment: но в таком случае у меня теперь " 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2026' in position 649: character maps to <undefined> " ошибочка другая.

Comment: Может расскажет кто за что минус? Или я один такой особенный у которого такая проблема?

Comment: в ответе кусок рабочего кода из одного проекта. Ошибка codec can't encode character '\u2026' - без принта попробуйте, похоже на ошибку ввода вывода если из под виндовс.

Comment: не помещайте текст в вопрос в виде картинки. Если не знаете как скопировать текст из консоли, задайте отдельный вопрос специально об этом.

Comment: не вызывайте слепо `.decode(resp_obj.encoding).encode('utf-8').decode("utf-8")`. Почитайте о разнице между байтами и Юникодом (текстом). Если вы хотите вывести html в консоль, то преобразуйте в unicode перед печатью. Если lxml неправильно кодировку в вашем случае определяет, то [можно beautifulsoup4 использовать, чтобы кодировку найти](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15302125/4279). См. также [urllib Python 3.4 проблема с кодировкой](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/452278/23044)

Comment: Я конечно все понимаю, но чем поможет в данном случае текст из консоли? Уже не вызываю, нет надобности в ответе дан нормальный вариант не требующий этого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример, кодировка и сайта и вывода считаем utf-8

```
r = requests.get(url.strip())
html = lxml.html.fromstring(r.text)
title = html.xpath('//title/text()')[0].strip()
content = etree.tounicode(html.get_element_by_id('page_content'))
```

Рекомендуется использовать tostring, но это зависит от версии lxml на компьютере

```
Deprecated: use tostring(el, encoding='unicode') instead.
```

Только через xpath

```
import requests
import lxml.html

url = 'https://freelance.ru/projects/?spec=4&page=1'
r = requests.get(url)
html = lxml.html.fromstring(r.text)
title = html.xpath('//title/text()')[0].strip()
first_topic = html.xpath(".//*[@id='col_center']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/h2/a/span/text()")
```

Comment: тут беда еще в том что сайт в CP-1251 кодировке. Я попробую ваше решение и отпишусь получилось или нет.

Comment: если через requests, то лучше всего прямо в нем указать кодировку, переведет сразу в рабочий внутренний вариант, или decode encode cp-1251

Comment: tostring(el, encoding='cp-1251'), но сработает ли, не знаю

Comment: Смотрите может у нас разные lxml, но AttributeError: module 'lxml' has no attribute 'html'

Comment: import lxml.html

Comment: from lxml import etree

Comment: С этим разобрался

Comment: А можете подсказать, как в requests.get сразу кодировку указать?

Comment: Уже не надо он сам подобрал, спасибо вам большое что помогли, я уже не первый раз сталкиваюсь просто что не могу вывести в нормальном виде в терминал.

Comment: там возможно все собрать через xpath, даже удобнее будет, можно весь поднятый мусор убрать, но это уже на любителя.

Comment: Я через xpath и стараюсь все получать