# Python: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, консоль, unicode

Добрый день
Считываю utf8-файл и вывожу в консоль. При попытке вывести букву "И" возникает ошибка:

```
File "I:\ProgramFile\Anaconda\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 15, in decode  
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)  
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 1: character maps to < undefined >
```

Воспроизводится на вот таком примере:

```
test_text_1 = "Задача\n"
test_text_2 = "Итератор"

file = open('temp.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
file.write(test_text_1)
file.write(test_text_2)
file.close()

text = open('temp.txt', 'rb')

for byte_code in text:
    print(byte_code.strip())
    test_text = byte_code.decode('cp1251')
    print(test_text.strip())
```

Первое слово выводится нормально, а на втором - ошибка. Никак не могу найти способ побороть проблему.

**UPD:** Видимо я описал проблему слишком широко, исправляюсь:

***Как конвертировать "И" из utf-8 в cp1251?*** Для "А" всё работает, а для "И" - нет.

Код:

```
byte1 = 'А'.encode('utf-8')
byte2 = 'И'.encode('utf-8')
print(byte1, byte2)
test1 = byte1.decode('cp1251')
print(test1)
test2 = byte2.decode('cp1251')
print(test2)
```

Comment: Опишите **конкретную** проблему, которую вы пытаетесь решить. Пока что, судя по вашему коду, вы пытаетесь превратить нормальный текст в "кракозябры".

Comment: Конвертировать текст из внутреннего представления Python  в cp1251 очень просто: `'текст'.encode('cp1251')`. В итоге получаются байты, которые уже можно применить куда вам нужно.

Comment: С кодировкой в Python может это поможет? https://saitsozdanie.ru/forum/index.php?topic=8850.0 тоже долго искал

Answer (score 7):

Чтобы напечатать файл, содержащий текст в utf-8 кодировке, в консоль (аналог `type filename` в `cmd.exe`) в Питоне:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import shutil
import sys

with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(file, sys.stdout)
```

Если хочется напечатать Юникодные символы, которые непредставимы в `chcp` кодировке (OEM code page), то см. [Как из Python вывести на Windows-консоль строку в Юникоде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/141035/23044)

Answer (score 3):

Если у вас файл записан в кодировке utf-8, то и декодировать нужно из кодировки utf-8:

```
...
for byte in text:
    print(byte.strip())
    text = byte.decode('utf-8')
    print(text.strip())
```

Результат:

```
b'\xd0\x97\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb0\xd1\x87\xd0\xb0'
Задача
b'\xd0\x98\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80'
Итератор
```

Когда вы записываете текст в файл в какой-то кодировке, вы фактически превращаете внутреннее представление текста в байты в указанной кодировке. Чтобы правильно декодировать эти байты обратно во внутреннее представление, при декодировании нужно указать ту же кодировку, что и при записи.

Comment: Не знаю как у вас, но у меня при декодировании в utf-8 выводит:   b'\xd0\x97\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb0\xd1\x87\xd0\xb0'  
������  
b'\xd0\x98\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80'  
��������

Comment: @Kavaru, как у меня выводится я показал. У вас вывод идет на консоль системы или в IDE?

Comment: @Kavaru, "у меня при декодировании в utf-8 выводит" - декодирование идет **из** байт в кодировке utf-8 (или в другой кодировке) во внутреннее представление Python, кодирование - наоборот, из внутреннего представления в байты в указанной кодировке.