# проблема с cp1251.py

Tags: python

всем здраствуйте, писал скрипт который должен был взаимодействовать в текстовым файлом, искать заданное пользователем значение и выводить все сходства

Код:

```
search = input("Поиск значения:")
f = open('test.txt')
result = f.read()
f.close()
c = text.count(search)
while c > 0:
    print(search)
    c = 1
```

Ошибка:

```
File "C:\python\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode                                                                                                                      
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]                                                                                                               
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 114: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: 0x98 это тильда, что-то я ее не наблюдаю в вашем примере кода.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517085/python-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x98)

Comment: Добавьте полный стектрейс ошибки.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja у тильды код 126, он же 0x7e в шестнадцатеричной системе. Не понятно как у вас тильда получилась. Ошибка происходит при чтении файла скорее всего (чтобы не гадать нужен полный стектрейс), и байт 0x98 как раз в файле.

Comment: @insolor, вы правы. Это я в cp1252 случайно заглянул.

Answer (score 0):

Используй для работы с файлами контекстный менеджер. Ошибка заключается в том, что при вызове `open` ты не указываешь что за кодировка, поэтому выходит ошибка. Также лучше использовать конструкцию `with`, чтобы не писать `f.close()` (`with` делает это сам)

Исправленный код:

```
search = input("Поиск значения:")
with open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    result = f.read()
c = result.count(search)
while c > 0:
    print(search)
    c = 1
```

Comment: encoding - это не формат файла, это кодировка.