# Ошибка в работе httpie: AttributeError: 'TextTranscodingwrapper' object has no attribute 'buffer'

Tags: python, httpie

Пишу по уроку команду http и *название сайта*, после этого независимо от выбранного сайта в конце вместо html-каши выдает такую ошибку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
HTIP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: ...
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
http: error: AttributeError: 'TextTranscodingwrapper' object has no attribute 'buffer'
```

Comment: Попробуйте выключить [`win-unicode-console`](https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console/issues/16) (не используйте этот модуль с библитеками, которые не ожидают изменений, вносимых `win-unicode-console`—к примеру, я обычно явно активирую его `py -mrun ваш-скрипт.py` то  есть по умолчанию `win-unicode-console` выключен). Связанный вопрос: [Как из Python вывести на Windows-консоль строку в Юникоде?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/141035/23044)