# html, который декодится в utf-8 даёт UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: html, python, utf-8

У меня есть код, который должен получать HTML со страницы. Проблема в том, что когда я делаю `decode('utf-8')`, он выдаёт ошибку `UnicodeEncodeError`. Вот кусок кода, который это делает:

```
test = urllib.request.urlopen(('https://vk.com/id375629436')).read()   
print(test.decode('utf-8', 'replace'))
```

Ошибка дословно:

> ```
> 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xbb' in position 5681: character maps to <undefined>.
> ```

Comment: похоже, Вы пытатесь раскодировать текст в cp1251 с помощью utf8. А это сложно сделать без ошибок.

Comment: Если print() убрать, то ошибка пропадёт. Чтобы воспроизвести ошибку: `print('\xbb')` (ни utf-8, ни html тут ни при чём). Чтобы  печатать Unicode на Windows: [Как из Python вывести на Windows-консоль строку в Юникоде?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/141035/23044)

Comment: @KoVadim encode значит закодировать (Unicode -> bytes). print() пытается здесь кавычку (») закодировать, но в консоли cp866 (oem code page) не имеет этого символа, что к ошибке ведёт. Можно поставить win-unicode-console, чтобы Unicode API использовать для вывода в консоль. См. ссылку выше.

Comment: Без вывода в консоль ошибка есть? Если нет самый быстрый способ отказаться от вывода и использовать или логирование или вывод текстовый файл.