# Ошибка UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Доброе утро. 
Имеется бот телеграма который работает уже более 3х месяцев, но время от времени (2-5 дней) у него вылетает ошибка:

```
    Exception in thread WorkerThread2:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 54, in run
      File "main.py", line 200, in handle_text
      File "main.py", line 23, in log
      File "c:\users\root\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\encodings\cp866.py", line 19, in encode
        return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0456' in position 20: character maps to <undefined>

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
      File "site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 65, in run
      File "site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 98, in on_exception
      File "site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 206, in <lambda>
      File "site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 193, in or_set
      File "site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 206, in <lambda>
      File "site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 193, in or_set
      ................
```

Почему так происходит я не понимаю, в интернете пишут, что проблема с кодировками, но у меня все нормально.

У бота имеется лог и я вижу, что боту пишут и что бот пишет в ответ. Когда возникает ошибка, в логах ничего нет, никто ему ничего не пишет, он просто берет и попадает в бесконечный цикл.

Подскажите в чем проблема или направьте на путь истинный. Спасибо

Comment: Потому что виндовая консолька (по умолчанию) не поддерживает юникод; см. [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/359348/178213). Падает именно лог, поэтому в логах ничего и нет :)

Comment: @andreymal хм, интересно) Вы правы, это проблема виндовой консоли, в самом pycharme я не наблюдаю этой проблемы, а когда компилирую бота через (Pyinstaller) в один exe файл - то проблема появляется

Comment: @ВладимирВ.: исчезает ли ошибка, если вы обновите Питон?