# bs4 python непонятная ошибка при парсинге жж

Tags: python, веб-скрейпинг

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os, re
import sys, traceback    


#это тхт файл со списками линков на все посты жж
#он имеет вид:
#November 15th, 2006 - Волков Сергей Владимирович  
#(no subject)  
#http://salery.livejournal.com/339.html

#November 19th, 2006 - Волков Сергей Владимирович  
#Впечатления от комментариев  
#http://salery.livejournal.com/767.html и т.д. до конца жж

LINKS = 'C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\to.txt'


def main():
    f = open(LINKS, 'r')

    for i in f:

        try:
            match = re.match('http', i)

            if match:
                r = requests.get(i, 'html.parser')
                soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
                t = (soup.find('td', colspan='2').text) 
                print(t, '\n', i)
                input()

            else:
                pass

        except ValueError:
            print(traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info())[1])  
            input()

    input()
```

вот что выдает консоль: первые два поста из файла тхт парсятся норм, 5-й тоже; на 3,4 посты и далее до конца выдается текст:
    **File "C:\Users....\Desktop\Volkov\posts.py", line 22, in main

    print(t, '\n', i)**

Вопросы:
 1. как прикрепить тхт файл для желающих проверить в чем дело?
 2. в чем ошибка?
 3. могу послать тхт по мылу
 **4. я словил ошибку:

 http://salery.livejournal.com/947.html

  Error: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2026' in position 54: character maps to undefined**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не нужно сюда прикреплять ваш файл со ссылками. Вместо этого, сохраните html страничку, которая ваш код ломает в локальный файл. Проверьте что html из файла действительно продолжает ту же ошибку вызывать (вместо `r.content`, подставьте `open('input.html', 'rb').read()`). Затем удалите из него половину, проверьте что ошибку осталась. Если ошибка исчезла, то удалите другую половину.  Проверьте наличие ошибки. Повторяйте до тех пор, пока у вас не останется небольшой кусок html, который позволяет вам ошибку воспроизвести. Вставьте этот небольшой кусок html прямо в ваш код (вместо open().read())

Comment: что такое   'input.html'?  @jfs

Comment: *" сохраните html страничку, которая ваш код ломает в локальный файл."* -- `input.html` это локальный файл куда вы сохранили `r.content`, который ломает ваш код.

Comment: @jfs спасиб, но один хрен не могу понять, код то придется полностью переписать, я ж делаю итерацию по линкам, а тут 1 файл

Comment: @jfs извините мою тупость, я ультралюбитель. так?
def main():
        try:
            r = requests.get(путьДоХТМЛ, 'html.parser')
            soup = BeautifulSoup(open(путьДоХТМЛ, 'rb').read(), 'html.parser')
            t = (soup.find('td', colspan='2').text) 
            print(t)
            input()
        except ValueError:
            print(traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info())[1])             
            input()

Comment: да, для вопроса следует создать минимальный пример кода, задача которого продемонстрировать проблему, он не должен ничего другого делать (когда проблема разрешится, вы его просто выбрасываете), а не публиковать весь код, который у вас есть. В комментарии код не публикуйте. Обновите ваш вопрос вместо этого.

Comment: @jfs так я и привел минимальный кусок кода в вопросе, а еще более минимальный - вот: "print(t, '\n', i)"

Comment: нет, код у вас не является минимальным (можно убрать из него части, а проблема останется). Мне кажется я вам уже приводил ссылку: [mcve]

Comment: @jfs если убрать из него части, это уже не будет код. в любом случае спасибо

Comment: если вы прочтёте ссылку, которую я дал, то вы поймёте, что это не так. Не поленитесь, прочитайте ссылку -- она вам поможет не только для данного вопроса, но и для многих будущих проблем: сократит время, требуемое для отладки, а публикация минимального самодостаточного примера поможет другим помочь вам.

Comment: @jfs вот ошибка здесь первая: http://salery.livejournal.com/947.html
Error: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2026' in position 54: character maps to undefined

Comment: [Как из Python вывести на Windows-консоль строку в Юникоде?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/141035/23044)

Comment: @jfs спасибо, все сделал. все тексты вытащил