# Не запускается python скрипт из книги

Tags: python

Не могу сделать упражнение из книги "Лёгкий способ выучить Python (3-е издание)".

[image: пример в книге]

Ввёл как написано:

```
 # coding: utf8
x = u"Существует %d типов людей." % 10
binary = "Python"
do_not = u"нет"
y = u"Те, кто понимает %r, и те, кто — %s." % (binary, do_not)

print x
print y

print u"Я сказал: %s." % x
print u"А еще я сказал: '%s'." % y

hilarious = False
joke_evaluation = u"Разве это не смешно?! %r"

print joke_evaluation % hilarious

w = u"Это часть строки слева..."
e = u"а это справа."

print w + e
```

Но в Powershell возникает какая-то ошибка:

[image: ошибка]

Объясните, пожалуйста, что я сделал не так?

Comment: По поводу заголовка вопроса. Программы в pythpn НЕ компилируются

Comment: Мне изменили заголовок вопроса. Изначально он звучал так: "Не могу сделать упражнение из книги "Лёгкий способ выучить Python"

Comment: Прошу прощения, не заметил

Comment: Пожалуйста используйте текст, а не картинки, чтобы добавить код, сообщения об ошибках. С таким общим заголовком ваш вопрос практически бесполезен для будущих посетителей из поисковика (основная аудитория Stack Overflow). (Хороший заголовок содержал бы сообщение об ошибке, с намёком как она была получена). Если не знаете как скопировать текст, спрашивайте. См. [Как из Python вывести на Windows-консоль строку в Юникоде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/141035/23044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С python-кодом у вас всё хорошо. Проблема в консоле. В данном случае, вероятно, она у вас имеет кодировку ср866, при этом вы используете символ "—" (\u2014). В этом и сложность. Об этом же и говорит текст ошибки. Решения следующие:

1. Не использовать в выводе символ "—" и ему подобные.
2. Воспользоваться средой IDLE раз вы используете Windows
3. Изменить кодировку консоли PowerShell`a
4. Если это не принципиально при чтении книги, то воспользоваться
   он-лайн редактором. Вот для [примера](https://repl.it/Joph/0)

Comment: Большое спасибо. А я думал, что нет разницы между обычным дефисом и тире. Оказывается есть.

Comment: @USSeR если шрифт в консоли настроен, то можно печатать самые разные Unicode символы (BMP) независимо от текущей кодировки консоли, к примеру, помощью win-unicode-console пакета. См. ссылку на вопрос выше