# Проблема с кодировкой cp1252 в Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, cp1251

Добрый вечер!

Проблема следующего характера:

```
file_msg = input('Enter text files with your message: ')  
file_with_msg = open(file_msg + '.txt').read()
```

Открываю файл с текстом на русском языке, а при попытке вывести текст в cmd, выводятся иероглифы непонятные.
Подскажите, как можно решить данную проблему?
Кодировка текста - cp1252
Кодировка консоли - 866.

Результат вывода:
`C:\>python test.py 
Enter text files with your message: msg2 
i>??YN??????чN'`

Используя `print(ascii(file_with_msg))` получаю
`C:\>python test.py 
Enter text files with your message: msg2 
'\xef\xbb\xbf\xd0\u0178\xd1\u20ac\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\u201a'`

Comment: может всё же 1251? открыть с указанием кодировки можно просто: `open(file_msg + '.txt', encoding='cp1251')`... какие грабли будут с виндовой консольлью — я не знаю...

Comment: покажите код для вывода в консоль. Покажите результат (что вы видите). Покажите `print(ascii(file_with_msg))` (сократите файл до минимума—если одно слово как "иероглифы" выводится, достаточно одно слово). Покажите результат `print('\u0430\u0431\u0432')` Какая версия Питона?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Проблемы с кодировкой Python 2.7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229015/23044)

Comment: Грешно весьма в наше время использовать однобайтовые кодировки.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как из Python вывести на Windows-консоль строку в Юникоде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/141035/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам следует использовать `utf-8-sig` кодировку при чтении файла:

```
with open('файл.txt', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
    text = file.read()
print(text)  # -> Привет
```

Когда вы читаете этот файл, используя `locale.getpreferredencoding()` кодировку (по умолчанию для `open()`), то получается `'\xef\xbb\xbf'`, что (превратив в байты) выглядит как [BOM в UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8).