# Python считывание string с несколькими строками из консоли

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, консоль, unicode

Мне нужно считать из консоли строку в юникоде, которая имеет такой вид:

```
যুদ্ধ এবং শান্তি

প্রথম ভলিউম

অংশ এক

আমি

ভাল, আমার রাজকুমার জেনোয়া এবং লুক্কা Appanages তুলনায় আর নেই, উদাহরণস্বরূপ, Buonaparte পরিবার এর। না, আমি আপনাকে সাবধান করে দিচ্ছি যে যদি আপনি আমাকে বলেন না যে আমরা যুদ্ধ করেছি, যদি আপনি এখনও নিজেকে সমস্ত দুষ্টতা দূর করতে অনুমতি দেন, তাহলে এই খ্রীষ্টশত্রু (আমার শব্দ, আমি বিশ্বাস করি) - এর সব অত্যাচার - আমি আর আপনাকে জানি না আপনি আর আমার বন্ধু নন, আপনি আর নেই আমার কথা, আপনি বলছেন যে হিসাবেওয়েল, হ্যালো, হ্যালো আমি আপনাকে ভয় পাচ্ছি যে দেখতে 2, আপনি কি জানেন?
```

Как я могу это сделать? Питон записывает строку только до первого перевода каретки.

Comment: Не проще/лучше из файлика считывать? `f = open('text.txt', encoding='utf-8')` `text = f.read` `print(text)`

Comment: а на русский перевести можно ?

Comment: Нет, из файлика нельзя читать. 
Язык не решает, поэтому взял рандомный.

Comment: @МаксимЛенский: в оригинале это на французском. Похоже на начало "Война и Мир" Толстого.

Comment: @jfs да я перевёл через yandex translate ...бенгальский вроде бы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Питоне по умолчанию строки из стандартного ввода как Unicode приходят. Ничего специального не надо делать.

[`sys.stdin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) это файл, который предоставляет доступ к стандартному вводу. Вы можете использовать обычные методы для работы с файлом. К примеру, чтобы прочитать весь возможно многострочный ввод в одну строку:

```
text = sys.stdin.read()
```

Если текст непредставим в кодировке текущего окружения (к примеру, `UnicodeDecodeErrror` получаете), то в зависимости от конкретной задачи можно [`PYTHONIOENCODING` переменную окружения](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) настроить или поставить [`win-unicode-console` пакет](https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console).

Схожий вопрос про `sys.stdout`: [Как из Python вывести на Windows-консоль строку в Юникоде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/141035/23044)

Answer (score 0):

```
my_string =""
while True:
    try:
        my_string += input() 
        # или + my_string += input() + "\n", если нужны символы перевода строки
        # или raw_input() для python 2.x
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```