# Python парсинг html страницы

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

Хочу спарсить авито, но когда получаю `html` выводит какую-то бурду. Подскажите что не так.

Пример полученного `html`:

```html
    href="https://m.avito.ru/rossiya/kvartiry">\n  \n <title>\xd0\x9a\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd1\x80\xd1\x8b - \xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb6\xd0\xb0, \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd1\x83\xd0\xbf\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xb8 \xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xb1\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb7 \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2 \xd0\xb2 \xd0\xa0\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd1\x81\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb8 \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0 Avito </title>\n <meta name="description" content="\xd0\x9e\xd0\xb1\xd1\x8a\xd1\x8f\xd0\xb2\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f \xd0\xbe \xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb6\xd0\xb5, \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd1\x83\xd0\xbf\xd0\xba\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xb8 \xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xba\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd1\x80 \xd0\xb1\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb7 \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2 \xd0\xb2
```

Вот так вывожу это добро:

```
def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    print(response.read())
```

Как можно это исправить?

Comment: Да всё в порядке вроде, выглядит как байтовая строка с кодировкой utf-8 и экранированием не-ascii символов при выводе. Какие конкретно проблемы вы испытываете? И вообще как вы это получили?

Comment: Если вы хотите просто получить адекватный вывод, то .decode('utf-8')

Comment: @andreymal добавил код, как получаю это. Не подскажите куда это вводить? На питоне пишу второй день.

Comment: print(response.read().decode('utf-8')) — если пишете второй день, изучите разницу между байтовыми строками и юникодными строками

Comment: @andreymal я вчера писал парсер yahoo finance, но там мне не выводило байтовых строк, хотя метод получения html тот же. Почему ваш код выводит ошибку "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20bd' in position 13562: character maps to <undefined>"

Comment: «но там мне не выводило байтовых строк» — выводило, вы просто не обратили внимания на это

Comment: «Почему ваш код выводит ошибку» — потому что у вас видимо Windows-консоль, которая не способна вывести весь набор символов, который есть на странице avito — питон в этом не совсем виноват. Читайте [Как из Python вывести на Windows-консоль строку в Юникоде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/359348/178213)

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 2):

Доверьте `BeautifulSoup` самому парсить страницу:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    rs = urlopen(url)
    root = BeautifulSoup(rs, 'html.parser')
    print(root)
```

Comment: не выходит. Выдает ошибку: "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20bd' in position 13437: character maps to <undefined>"

Comment: Дайте угадаю, вы выводите в консоль виндовс? cmd? Так, я тестировал код из вопроса для ссылки `"https://m.avito.ru/rossiya/kvartiry"`

Comment: `https://www.avito.ru/rossiya/kvartiry?s_trg=10` пытаюсь получить html вот этой ссылки. вывожу в саблайме (но кажется там выводит с помощью cmd)

Comment: @LetsDrum, я выводил в внутренней консоли PyCharm, та юникодные символы спокойно отображает, в отличии от ущербной виндувсовой :) Попробуйте, тогда в файл сохранять и из него изучать html, тем более, что они обычно приходят большими и в буфер консоли не влазят. Да и... вам ведь нужно парсить? Тогда смотрите через браузер структуру, а в коде парсите. Есть еще один способ по бороться с консолью винды -- https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/d8a2a34aa1a2f13218ded9191a3ea1d33bc28bf1/Check%20with%20notification/all_common.py#L10

Comment: так проблема в том, что когда я делал в первый раз, создавал переменную `table = soup.find('div', class_='catalog')`, то при запуске скрипта выдавало ошибку о том, мол данного элемента в html не существует. я начал пробовать спарсить весь html и посмотреть что же не так. В итоге, html был отображен байтовыми строками в кодировке utf-8. Такие дела.

Comment: Сохраните в файл и через редактор смотрите -- консоль для просмотра html обычно не подходит -- разве что для отдельных тегов.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.6, работает без проблем:

```
import urllib

url = 'https://m.avito.ru/rossiya/kvartiry'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
print(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

response.read() - возвращает нам строку bytes, соответственно декодируем её в utf-8 и всё работает