# Python. Ошибка в кодировке при парсинге с помощью прекрасного супа

Tags: python, кодировка, requests, beautiful-soup

Во время выполнения скрипта выдаёт ошибку

```
 UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xb2' 
   in position 3511: character maps to <undefined>
```

Сам скрипт:

```
def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read().decode('utf-8')
def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    pages = soup.find('div', class_='catalog-list js-catalog-list clearfix').find_all('div')
    print(pages)
def main():
    parse(get_html('https://www.avito.ru/rossiya/kvartiry?s_trg=3'))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Использую SublimeText 3, Windows 10, CMD, Python 3.7. Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить.

Comment: Выдаёт где? В вашем коде целых 13 строк — в какой именно?

Comment: Если в print — то в предыдущем вопросе я вам уже предлагал читать это: [Как из Python вывести на Windows-консоль строку в Юникоде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/141035)

Comment: Ошибка при выводе `pages`

Comment: Читайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/141035

Comment: @andreymal я уже делал как описано в ответе по данной ссылке, но мне не помогает это. Установил win_unicode_console и ничего не изменилось. Ошибка та же и в том же месте.

Comment: @LetsDrum: задайте отдельный вопрос о том как у вас `print('\xb2')`  не работает в *"SublimeText 3, Windows 10, CMD, Python 3.7"* (тут возможно проблема то как SublimiteText ваш скрипт запускает. Если руками из Windows консоли запустить должно работать). На будущее, если ответ вам "не помогает" -- то попробуйте ещё раз его прочитать. К примеру, если в ответе сказано "Простой print(unicode_string) теперь работает без установки дополнительного ПО" (фраза даже выделена курсивом для большей заметности), то не надо ставить дополнительное ПО такое как win-unicode-console)

Answer (score 0):

```
parsed_html_object = BeautifulSoup(html_string, 'lxml')
```

`lxml` должен быть установлен, `sudo pip3 install lxml`