# Выдаёт ошибку когда пытаюсь прочитать текстовый файл

Tags: python, python-3.x

Учусь по книге: Зед Шоу - Легкий способ выучить Python 3

```py
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

txt = open(filename)

print(f"Содержимое файла {filename}:")
print(txt.read())

print("Снова введите имя файла:")
file_again = input("> ")

txt_again = open(file_again)

print(txt_again.read())
```

При в вводе команды, выдает **вот что**.

> C:\Python\pabota2>pabota2.py pop_sample.txt

Содержимое файла `pop_sample.txt`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\pabota2\pabota2.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(txt.read())
  File "C:\Users\mariy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 112: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: ну для начала, вы используете версию 3.8, а книга написана явно не на ней, но это не главное, из текста ошибки видно - что дело тут в кодировке, для начала я бы порекомендовал установить, например, версию 3.7.4, она более стабильна и отлично работает.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Но у меня когда я пишу команду выводит, что 3.7. Python 3.7.0

Comment: \Python\Python38-32\lib\

Comment: а еще проверьте, ту ли версию языка вы скачали, ибо сейчас архитектура многих процессоров x64, а я вижу пайтон 32

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/33868/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-python-readline-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-utf-8-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-charmap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исключение [`UnicodeDecodeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html?highlight=unicodedecodeerror#UnicodeDecodeError) возникает в ситуации невозможности декодирования последовательности байтов в символы [Юникода](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4). Python версий 3+ оперирует исключительно со строками в одной из кодировок юникода (подробнее об этом можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html)). Таким образом, для того чтобы получить возможность работать с текстовыми данными в других кодировках, эти данные неоходимо транслировать в кодировку Юникода. Как следует из текста исключения, произошла ошибка **при декодировании**. Единственное место в вашем коде, где происходит неявное декодирование - `txt.read()`. Все это означет то, что при открытии файла `txt = open(filename)` была указана (опять неявно) неверная кодировка. По умолчанию такая кодировка является платформозависимой (ее можно узнать через `import locale; locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`). Подробнее о функции [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open).

В вашем случае следует явно указать кодироку открываемого файла, отличную от `'cp1251'` (ваша локальная кодировка):

```
txt = open(filename, encoding=X)
```

где `X` - строка обозначающая кодировку конкретного файла. Попробуйте навскидку `'utf-8'`, `'latin1'`.

Далее, если не получится, попробуйте "замять" ошибки. К списку тестируемых кодировок прибавьте `'cp1251'`:

```
txt = open(filename, encoding=X, errors='replace')
```

или

```
txt = open(filename, encoding=X, errors='ignore')
```

Есть также вариант, что необходимый файл просто не поддаётся декодированию. В таком случае у вас все еще есть возможность прочитать "сырые данные":

```
txt = open(filename, 'br')
```

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь все работает.